# What are the differences between flex-basis and width?

Tags: css, flexbox, width

There have been questions and articles about this, but nothing conclusive as far as I can tell. The best summary I could find is

> *flex-basis* allows you to specify the initial/starting size of the element, before anything else is computed. It can either be a percentage or an absolute value.

...which in itself doesn't say much about the behavior of elements with *flex-basis* set. With my current knowledge of flexbox I don't see why that couldn't describe *width* also.

I'd like to know how exactly *flex-basis* is different from *width* in practice:

- If I replace *width* with *flex-basis*(and vice versa), what will change visually?
- What happens if I set both to a different value? What happens if they have the same value?
- Are there some special cases where using either *width* or *flex-basis* would have a significant difference to using the other?
- How do *width* and *flex-basis* differ when used in conjunction with other flexbox styles, such as *flex-wrap*, *flex-grow* and *flex-shrink*?
- Any other significant differences?

---

**Edit/clarification**: This question has been asked in a different format in [What exactly flex-basis property sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569229/what-exactly-flex-basis-property-sets) but I felt a more direct comparison or summary of the differences of *flex-basis* and *width* (or *height*) would be nice.

Comment: Best [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/even-more-about-how-flexbox-works-explained-in-big-colorful-animated-gifs-a5a74812b053/) explaining the flex basis, flex grow and shrink altogether

Answer (score 522, accepted):

### Consider `flex-direction`

The first thing that comes to mind when reading your question is that `flex-basis` doesn't always apply to `width`.

When `flex-direction` is `row`, `flex-basis` controls width.

But when `flex-direction` is `column`, `flex-basis` controls height.

---

### Key Differences

Here are some important differences between `flex-basis` and `width` / `height`:

- `flex-basis` applies only to flex items. Flex containers  (that aren't also flex items) will ignore `flex-basis` but can use `width` and `height`.
- `flex-basis` works only on the main axis. For example, if you're in `flex-direction: column`, the `width` property would be needed for sizing flex items horizontally.
- `flex-basis` has no effect on absolutely-positioned flex items. `width` and `height` properties would be necessary. [Absolutely-positioned flex items do not participate in flex layout](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items).
- By using the `flex` property, three properties – `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` – can be neatly combined into one declaration. Using `width`, the same rule would require multiple lines of code.

---

### Browser Behavior

In terms of how they are rendered, there should be *no difference* between `flex-basis` and `width`, unless `flex-basis` is `auto` or `content`.

*From the spec:*

> [**7.2.3. The `flex-basis` property**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#flex-basis-property)
>
> For all values other than `auto` and `content`, `flex-basis` is resolved the same way as `width` in horizontal writing modes.

But the impact of `auto` or `content` may be minimal or nothing at all. More from the spec:

> [***`auto`***](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#valdef-flex-basis-auto)
>
> When specified on a flex item, the `auto` keyword retrieves the value
>   of the main size property as the used `flex-basis`. If that value is
>   itself `auto`, then the used value is `content`.
>
> [***`content`***](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#valdef-flex-basis-auto)
>
> Indicates automatic sizing, based on the flex item’s content.
>
> *Note: This value was not present in the initial release of Flexible
>   Box Layout, and thus some older implementations will not support it.
>   The equivalent effect can be achieved by using `auto` together with a
>   main size (`width` or `height`) of `auto`.*

So, according to the spec, `flex-basis` and `width` resolve identically, unless `flex-basis` is `auto` or `content`. In such cases, `flex-basis` may use content width (which, presumably, the `width` property would use, as well).

---

### The `flex-shrink` factor

It's important to remember the initial settings of a flex container. Some of these settings include:

- `flex-direction: row` - flex items will align horizontally
- `justify-content: flex-start` - flex items will stack at the start of the line on the main axis
- `align-items: stretch` - flex items will expand to cover the cross-size of the container
- `flex-wrap: nowrap` - flex items are forced to stay in a single line
- `flex-shrink: 1` - a flex item is allowed to shrink

Note the last setting.

Because flex items are allowed to shrink by default (which prevents them from overflowing the container), the specified `flex-basis` / `width` / `height` may be overridden.

For example,  `flex-basis: 100px` or `width: 100px`, coupled with `flex-shrink: 1`, will not necessarily be 100px.

To render the specified width – *and keep it fixed* – you will need to disable shrinking:

```
div {
   width: 100px;
   flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

OR

```
div {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

OR, as recommended by the spec:

```
flex: 0 0 100px;    /* don't grow, don't shrink, stay fixed at 100px */
```

> [**7.2. Components of
>   Flexibility**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-components)
>
> Authors are encouraged to control flexibility using the `flex` shorthand
>   rather than with its longhand properties directly, as the shorthand
>   correctly resets any unspecified components to accommodate [common
>   uses](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common).

---

### Browser Bugs

Some browsers have trouble sizing flex items in nested flex containers.

### `flex-basis` ignored in a nested flex container. `width` works.

When using `flex-basis`, the container ignores the sizing of its children, and the children overflow the container. But with the `width` property, the container respects the sizing of its children and expands accordingly.

References:

- [Chrome does not expand flex parent according to children's content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45482350/3597276)
- [Flex item overflowing when using flex-basis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56063016/3597276)
- [Difference between width and flex-basis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38227597/3597276)
- [Flex-basis is being ignored when sizing nested flex containers.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=464210)
- [flex-basis:100px does something different from width:100px+flex-basis:auto](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=533627)

Examples:

- https://jsfiddle.net/t419zhra/ (source: [@Dremora](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38227597/3597276))
- https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NVxaoy (source [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50841/daniel))
- https://jsfiddle.net/voc9grx6/ (source: [Chromium Bugs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=533627))
- https://jsfiddle.net/qjpat9zk/ (source: [Chromium Bugs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=464210))

---

### flex items using `flex-basis` and `white-space: nowrap` overflow `inline-flex` container.  `width` works.

It seems that a flex container set to `inline-flex` doesn't recognize `flex-basis` on a child when rendering a sibling with `white-space: nowrap` (although it could just be an item with undefined width). The container doesn't expand to accommodate the items.

But when the `width` property is used instead of `flex-basis`, the container respects the sizing of its children and expands accordingly. This is not a problem in IE11 and Edge.

References:

- [inline flex container width not growing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46687444/3597276)
- [Inline flex container (display: inline-flex) is expanding the full width of parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40365718/3597276)

Example:

- https://jsfiddle.net/p18h0jxt/1/ (from first post above)

---

### `flex-basis` (and `flex-grow`) not working on table element

References:

- [Why does flex-box work with a div, but not a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41421512/3597276)
- [Why doesn't flex-grow: 1 work for a table in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58559734/3597276) (and Edge)

---

### `flex-basis` fails in Chrome and Firefox when the grandparent container is a shrink-to-fit element. The set-up works fine in Edge.

- [Absolutely positioned container not expanding width to fit flexbox content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59186681/3597276)

Like in the example presented in the link above, involving `position: absolute`, the use of `float` and `inline-block`, will also render the same flawed output ([jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t1d246n8/)).

---

### Bugs affecting IE 10 and 11:

- [`flex` shorthand declarations with unitless `flex-basis` values are ignored](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#4-flex-shorthand-declarations-with-unitless-flex-basis-values-are-ignored)
- [`flex-basis` doesn't account for `box-sizing: border-box`](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/blob/master/README.md#7-flex-basis-doesnt-account-for-box-sizingborder-box)
- [`flex-basis` doesn't support `calc()`](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/blob/master/README.md#8-flex-basis-doesnt-support-calc)
- [Importance is ignored on `flex-basis` when using `flex` shorthand](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/blob/master/README.md#13-importance-is-ignored-on-flex-basis-when-using-flex-shorthand)

Comment: How about `min-width:100px;`? Can it be an option to disable shrinking?

Comment: @Mori, yes, `flex-shrink` stops at `min-width`. The equivalent flex rule would be `flex: 1 0 100px`.

Comment: `flex: 1 0 100px` leads to the same result, but I'm not sure what you mean by "equivalent".

Comment: I mean why shouldn't we consider it equal to `flex: 0 0 100px`, for example?

Comment: @Mori, because then it's just equal to *width*. It needs the *flex-grow: 1* component to allow the element to grow from the minimum width, set by the *flex-basis*.

Comment: If you don't mind, you can also extend the Browser Bug section to say that `flex-basis` doesn't work if the grand parent element is a *shrink-to-fit* element (inline-block, float, position:absolute/fixed, etc) : https://jsfiddle.net/82dx9mrw/1/ .. the logic is almost the same as with inline-flex as parent element and nested flexbox since there is that *shrink-to-fit* behavior but differently.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Done. Thanks. I've encountered a number of additional browser bugs related to this question. I just haven't had the time to add them. I presume your question is motivated by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59186681/3597276), which you closed as a duplicate to this post, and which I didn't close as a duplicate because that particular bug wasn't represented here.

Comment: I was pretty sure that your answer covers those cases (that's why I closed that question) but checking now it seems not ... maybe I saw this in another of your answer or I simply concluded this myself. I will edit later and reference that question as example.

Comment: I just updated the answer. The dupe on that post is now relevant. @TemaniAfif

Comment: The key to my question was this part "Flex containers (that aren't also flex items) will ignore flex-basis"

Comment: There seems to be one key difference between `flex-basis` and `width`. The value of `flex-basis` is bounded below to `min-content`, such that values smaller than whatever `min-content` is compute to `min-content`. In other words, you can't make the box size smaller than its content. With `width` you can do whatever you want, and if it's smaller than the content, the content will overflow. For an example, see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/63131269/2607891

Comment: another example that can be added to the bug list: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65848639/8620333

Comment: Flex basis of 0px is different than width of 0px. Kevin Powell video on it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u044iM9xsWU&t=17m25s

Answer (score 41):

In addition to Michael_B's excellent summary it's worth repeating this:

> flex-basis allows you to specify the **initial/starting** size of the element, before anything else is computed. It can either be a percentage or an absolute value.

The important part here is **initial**.

By itself, this does resolve to width/height *until* the other flex grow/shrink properties come into play.

So. a child with

```
.child {
 flex-basis:25%;
 flex-grow:1;
}
```

will be 25% wide initially but then immediately expand as much as it can until the other elements are factored in. If there are none..it will be 100% wide/tall.

A quick demo:

```css
.flex {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  height: 25px;
  display: flex;
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
.child {
  flex-basis: auto;
  /* default */
  background: plum;
}
.value {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
.grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="child auto">Some Content</div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="child value">Some Content</div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="child grow">Some Content</div>
</div>
```

Experimenting with the `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` 
(or the shorthand `flex :fg fs fb`)...can lead to some interesting results.

Comment: I found that generally in flex context they both `flex-basis` and `width / height` set the initial / starting size of an element. For example `flex-basis: 200px` basically works the same as `flex-basis: auto; width: 200px;`. It looks like when `flex-basis` is not set to `auto` then it just overrides `width / height` value. The only difference that I see is the way content overflow is handled.

Answer (score 26):

There is one key difference between `flex-basis` and `width` (or `height`, depending on the current writing mode) apart from the flexible sizing aspect (`flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;`).

It originates from the exception in Flex Layout, that the automatic minimum size for flex items defaults to `min-content` instead of `0` as usual. In other words, the default `min-width: auto` computes to `min-content` instead of `0`.

The result is that `flex-basis` is (by default) bound below by `min-content`. If you specify a value smaller than `min-content`, for example `flex-basis: 0`, it will compute to `min-content`. This essentially means that (by default) you can't make the box's content overflow since the box has at least the size of the content.

This is a key difference to `width` which can size the box arbitrarily small (by default), since `min-width` defaults to `0`. If the value of `width` is smaller than `min-content`, the contents will overflow the box.

This behavior is mentioned in the spec, but only implicitly in a comment at the wrong place at the end of [7.1.1. Basic Values of `flex`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#flex-common).

> By default, flex items won’t shrink below their minimum content size (the length of the longest word or fixed-size element). To change this, set the min-width or min-height property. (See § 4.5 Automatic Minimum Size of Flex Items.)

As mentioned in the comment, setting a minimum size lowers the bound, and setting it to zero effectively disables it, making `flex-basis` behave again as expected.

But there are drawbacks. Firstly, there is no minimum size property for the main axis. You have to use the correct `min-width`/`min-height` or `min-block-size`/`min-inline-size` property for the current `flex-direction`. If you changed the `flex-direction`, you would need to again find the correct minimum size property.

Secondly, `flex-basis` can't be used anymore to distribute space towards proportionally sized boxes instead of simply adding to their initial size. For more details, see [Figure 7](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-none) in the spec.

Here is a minimal example. Set `min-width: 0` to make `flex-basis` behave as expected again.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container div {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 10px;
  /* disable any flexible sizing */
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  /* TOGGLE ME */
  /* min-width: 0; */
}

.mincontent {
  width: min-content;
}

.smallerflexbasis {
  flex-basis: 3ex;
}

.smallerwidth {
  width: 3ex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mincontent">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="smallerflexbasis">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="smallerwidth">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for. Thank you.

Comment: This part "As mentioned in the comment, setting a minimum size lowers the bound, and setting it to zero effectively disables it, making flex-basis behave again as expected." helped me solve my issue, thanks!

Comment: super useful, thanks! especially this link to the figure https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-none, I'd add this to the answer

Answer (score 8):

Possibly the most important point to add:

What if the browser doesn't support `flex`? In such a case, `width/height` take over and their values apply.

It is a very good idea - almost essential - to define `width/height` on elements, even if you then have a completely different value for `flex-basis`. Remember to test by disabling `display:flex` and seeing what you get.

Comment: Among the major browsers, the only ones that don't support flex properties are IE < 10. http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: @Michael_B Sure, and maybe it's just me but I have to support mobile browsers too, up to and including the Nintendo 3DS browser, which decidedly doesn't support `flex`.

Answer (score 5):

if you set a div's `min-width:600px`, if the window size goes under 600px, you will see a horizontal scrollbar which is not a good ux design.

If you set its `flex-basis:600px`, if the window size goes under 600px, that box will shrink and you will not see a horizontal bar.

Note that `flex-basis` applies only to the flex items.

Answer (score 4):

It makes a difference if you're wrapping.

Say, you set a child to `width:0` and expect it to wrap, well that's not going to happen. But with `flex-basis:0` it will wrap. (provided overflow isn't hidden)