# nested flex elements don't make parent grow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to compose a header with month names and all days in that month right below the name.

Days items have fixed width so I thought: why not use flexbox?

For some reasons `.day` elements are falling of their parent and parent does not grow.

Could you please give me a hint why `flex-basis: auto` doesn't make month-slot grow after days' slot overflow it?

As for implementation I've already found workaround with using `float: left` instead of using flexbox. But I cannot understand why it works this way.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.month {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.days {
  display: flex;
}

.day {
  flex: 0 0 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='month'>
    <div class='name'>Jan</div>
    <div class='days'>
      <div class='day'>1</div>
      <div class='day'>2</div>
      <div class='day'>3</div>
      <div class='day'>4</div>
      <div class='day'>5</div>
      <div class='day'>6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='month'>
    <div class='name'>Feb</div>
    <div class='days'>
      <div class='day'>1</div>
      <div class='day'>2</div>
      <div class='day'>3</div>
      <div class='day'>4</div>
      <div class='day'>5</div>
      <div class='day'>6</div>
      <div class='day'>7</div>
      <div class='day'>8</div>
      <div class='day'>9</div>
      <div class='day'>10</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='month'>
    <div class='name'>Mar</div>
    <div class='days'>
      <div class='day'>1</div>
      <div class='day'>2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/skyboyer/pen/MyzeLW

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/ytt7jb85/

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/xs946nfv/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `width: 2em` instead of `flex: 0 0 2em`.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
}
.month {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.days {
  display: flex;
}
.day {
  width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='month'>
    <div class='name'>Jan</div>
    <div class='days'>
      <div class='day'>1</div>
      <div class='day'>2</div>
      <div class='day'>3</div>
      <div class='day'>4</div>
      <div class='day'>5</div>
      <div class='day'>6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='month'>
    <div class='name'>Feb</div>
    <div class='days'>
      <div class='day'>1</div>
      <div class='day'>2</div>
      <div class='day'>3</div>
      <div class='day'>4</div>
      <div class='day'>5</div>
      <div class='day'>6</div>
      <div class='day'>7</div>
      <div class='day'>8</div>
      <div class='day'>9</div>
      <div class='day'>10</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='month'>
    <div class='name'>Mar</div>
    <div class='days'>
      <div class='day'>1</div>
      <div class='day'>2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem with your code is that Firefox and Chrome size `.month` taking the width of the contents into account, but not `flex-basis`.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
}
.month {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.days {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.main.big .day {
  flex: 0 0 2em;
}
.main.big > .month:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='main grow'>
  <div class='month'>
    <div class='name'>Jan</div>
    <div class='days'>
      <div class='day'>1</div>
      <div class='day'>2</div>
      <div class='day'>3</div>
      <div class='day'>4</div>
      <div class='day'>5</div>
      <div class='day'>6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='month'>
    <div class='name'>Feb</div>
    <div class='days'>
      <div class='day'>1</div>
      <div class='day'>2</div>
      <div class='day'>3</div>
      <div class='day'>4</div>
      <div class='day'>5</div>
      <div class='day'>6</div>
      <div class='day'>7</div>
      <div class='day'>8</div>
      <div class='day'>9</div>
      <div class='day'>10</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='month'>
    <div class='name'>Mar</div>
    <div class='days'>
      <div class='day'>1</div>
      <div class='day'>2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class='main big'>
  <div class='month'>
    <div class='name'>Jan</div>
    <div class='days'>
      <div class='day'>1</div>
      <div class='day'>2</div>
      <div class='day'>3</div>
      <div class='day'>4</div>
      <div class='day'>5</div>
      <div class='day'>6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='month'>
    <div class='name'>Feb</div>
    <div class='days'>
      <div class='day'>1</div>
      <div class='day'>2</div>
      <div class='day'>3</div>
      <div class='day'>4</div>
      <div class='day'>5</div>
      <div class='day'>6</div>
      <div class='day'>7</div>
      <div class='day'>8</div>
      <div class='day'>9</div>
      <div class='day'>10</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='month'>
    <div class='name'>Mar</div>
    <div class='days'>
      <div class='day'>1</div>
      <div class='day'>2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a bug. According to [Line Length Determination](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#line-sizing), when [determining the flex base size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#algo-main-item) of `.month` case E applies:

> size the item into the [available space](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-sizing/#terms) using its used [flex
>   basis](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-flex-basis) in place of its [main size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size), treating a value of
>   [`content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-basis-content) as [`max-content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-sizing/#width-height-keywords).

The intricacies of calculating a max-content size were moved to CSS Sizing 4:

> [**max-content inline size**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#max-content-inline-size): The box’s “ideal” [size](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#size) in the
>   [inline axis](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-writing-modes-3/#inline-axis). Usually the narrowest [inline size](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-writing-modes-3/#inline-size) it could
>   take while fitting around its contents if *none* of the soft wrap
>   opportunities within the box were taken. (See [§4 Intrinsic Size
>   Determination](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#intrinsic).)

In case of a [non-replaced block](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#block-intrinsic),

> The [max-content inline size](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#max-content-inline-size) of a [block container box](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#block-container-box) is the
>   inline-size of the box after layout, if all children are sized under a
>   [max-content constraint](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#max-content-constraint).

It explicitly says "after layout". It doesn't say something like "before flex layout". So `flex-basis: 2em` shouldn't be ignored, and should contribute to a bigger max-content size of the container.

Comment: so `width: 2em` + `flex-basis: auto` works differently from `flex-basis: 2em`
but why?

Comment: @Oriol yeah, I figured it out too but any idea why flex-basis doesn't work properly? Does `flex-basis` behave as width at all?

Comment: I'm starting to think this is a bug. According to [Intrinsic Sizes of Non-Replaced Blocks](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#block-intrinsic), the max-content contribution should be calculated after layout. But `flex-basis` is ignored and the width of the text is used instead, that seems "before layout" instead.

Comment: @Aziz, there's really no difference (as far as I can tell) between using `flex-basis` and `width` in this case. The code should work as-is. In fact, it works on IE11. But it fails in Chrome and FF.

Comment: If there is something in the spec describing this behavior @Oriol will find it :-) Here's what I found: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276

Comment: @Oriol, I don't think we even need to go that deep. The spec is pretty clear on `flex-basis` vis-a-vis `width` and `height`. In this particular situation, there should be no rendering difference. I agree with you that this may be a bug.