# Flex item override max-width property

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to make a `flex` container of divs in which all the divs will have the same width (two divs per line, 50% width of the container each of them).

I have set the divs inside the container with `max-width: 50%;` because I want them to be equals but it does not seem to respect this `max-width` when there is only one item in this line.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left" class="block">Left</div>
  <div id="center" class="block">
    <div class="flexContainer">
      <div class="flexDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexContainer">
      <div class="flexDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexContainer">
      <div class="flexDiv"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="block">Right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#container{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.block{
    flex: 1;
}

#left{
    background-color: green;
}

#center{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;  
    align-content: flex-start;
}

#right{
    background-color: orange;
}

.flexContainer{
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
}

.flexDiv{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5h9rjcd/) in which you can see how the width of the third element is bigger than the others.

Why the `flex` divs inside the container are not respecting `max-width` property?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean like this? - https://jsfiddle.net/yz9cd8e7/

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, exactly this. If you provide it with an explanation on an answer I will mark it as accepted :)

Comment: No problem...basically it was a `box-sizing` issue. @GCyrillus has already provided the answer.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you for the property! I did not know about this property before, so I am happy to learn a bit more each day :)

Comment: @Paulie_D I notice now that you have set `flex: 1 0 auto` on your jsfiddle. I know that the third parameter is `flex-basis` parameter but I do not know why you set it to auto. Can you explain it please?

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt. Older browsers used `flex-basis: 0` as the default

Comment: @Error404, here's some more info on `flex-basis: auto`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can reset or switch box model to include `padding` within `width` calculation:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#box-sizing

```
.flexContainer{
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;/* includes borders & padding within width calculation
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b5h9rjcd/1/