# trying to align two divs beside each other and failing

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In my code below, I would like the div with class `card-columns` to be inline/adjacent with the div having class `card-custom`.

I think what I'm trying is easy but I can't find the correct combination of display and floats to get it working.

I tried making the parent div a flex with `display: flex` hoping it would just work. But while it make it alongside it messed up the sizing of the first div.

Can someone help tell me what i'm doing wrong please?

I have a codepen example here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grxRza

```css
.maxWidth {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1370px;
  margin: 60px auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.card-columns {
  column-count: 5;
}
.intermission {
  color: blue;
  column-span: all;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.card-custom {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 430px;
  height: 220px;
  
}
```

```html
   
  <!-- intermission column span full -->
  <div class="intermission">
    
    <div class="card-custom">
    </div>
    
  <div class="card-columns">
    
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    </div><!-- end intermission card-columns -->
  </div><!-- end intermission div-->
```

Comment: Have you tried using style="display:inline-block;" for your divs?

Comment: Something like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOJyVj)?

Comment: Have a look at the examples provided here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track.

Add `display: flex` to the parent div:

```
.intermission {
  display: flex;   /* NEW */
  color: blue;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

The first div will shrink for two reasons:

- An initial setting of a flex container is `flex-shrink: 1`. This means that flex items are allowed to shrink (preventing them from overflowing the container).
- Another initial setting of a flex container is `flex-wrap: nowrap`. This means flex items are confined to a single line, allowing `flex-shrink: 1` to work.

Add `flex-shrink: 0` to the first div to disable the shrinking feature.

For more details, see *"The `flex-shrink` factor"* section in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34355447/3597276

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWxAJO?editors=1100)

```css
.intermission {
  display: flex;
  color: blue;
  border: 2px solid;
}
.card-columns {
  column-count: 5;
}
.card-custom {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 430px;
  height: 220px;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* NEW */
}
```

```html
<link href="http://afkweb.com/etc/bootstrap-4-alpha/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="intermission">
  <div class="card-custom"></div>
  <div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried float left or right? Make sure the total widths for card-column and card-custom do not exceed the total width size of the div or element containing them. Furthermore bootstrap grid system will help fix this with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your css

```
.card-custom{
    float: left;
}
```