# Scrollable div effects to its outside div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

See this code

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgb(238, 235, 235);
}

.header {
  background-color: rgb(126, 209, 171);
  height: 100px;  
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: rgb(209, 126, 165);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.row {
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="header">hello</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is fine. ".header"'s height is 100px after it is rendered. 
But after I insert lots of ".row" div into ".content" div, ".header"'s height shrinks less than 100px.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgb(238, 235, 235);
}

.header {
  background-color: rgb(126, 209, 171);
  height: 100px;  
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: rgb(209, 126, 165);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.row {
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="header">hello</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
    <div class="row">this is row</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to know why ".row" divs inside '.content' div effect to ".header" div, even though '.content' is scrollable. 
I know I can fix it by giving ".header" "flex-shrink: 0" but I don't know why I have to do it.

Comment: The reason is flexbox. You can learn more [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I always read the article. I know I'm missing something....

Comment: Instead of `height: 100px` on `.header`, use `flex: 0 0 100px`. See **The `flex-shrink` factor** in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34355447/3597276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "The main idea behind the flex layout is to give the container the ability to alter its items' width/height (and order) to best fill the available space (mostly to accommodate to all kind of display devices and screen sizes). A flex container expands items to fill available free space, or shrinks them to prevent overflow".

Taken from the *background* part from [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-background) (also in my comment).

The reason `.row` divs inside `.content` div effect to `.header` div, even though `.content` is that the container has the ability to alter the width/height of it's items - in order to best fill the space you have there.

Comment: "the container has the ability to alter the width/height of it's items" I understand perfectly now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**I believe you already have the answer there. ;)**

Reason is flex has default shrink value of `1`. So you have to change it to `0` in order to reset.

```
.item {
  flex-shrink: <number>; /* default 1 */
}
```

Read: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Then, why does the ".content" div of the first code not grow? It should grow as large as possible

Comment: I understand now.  It is because it is not necessary to grow.

Comment: @Nigiri, the `.content` div of the first code version *does grow*. It covers all the remaining height of the container.