# Set parent width based on flex-basis and width of children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to figure out a way for a parent flex element's width to be set dynamically by it's children, based on the children's flex-basis property.

For example, say I have a parent element (`display: flex`) with 12 children, each of which have a width of 100px and a flex-basis of 25%. In this case the width of the parent container should be set automatically to 400px. If I update the flex-basis to 50%, the container width should change to 200px.

Is this at all possible?

HTML

```
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item">1</li>
  <li class="item">2</li>
  // ...
  <li class="item">12</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #ff0;
  flex: 1 0 25%;
}

.item:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: #f0f;
}

.item:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  background-color: #0ff;
}
```

For convenience, [here's a live version](http://codepen.io/joshfarrant/pen/pEdJrA) of the above code for testing

Comment: Flex-basis is not the same as width.

Comment: I'm aware it's not the same as width, what I'm looking to do is dynamically calculate the parent's width based on the child's fixed with, and the child's flex-basis property.

Comment: Oh...then I suspect you want `display:inline-flex` not `flex` but that's not going to change the width of the parent. Flex-basis is calculated FROM the parent width.

Comment: Ok, so do you suspect that it's not possible then?

Comment: No....that's not the way flexbox works.

Comment: This may help clarify: [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)