# Flexbox layout losing proportions when reduced in size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm reproducing a golden spiral using CSS flexbox and percentage size for cells.

The round shape is drawn using a regular border and `border-radius` combination.

Everything is proportional until I resize the window to smaller widths.

I tried removing borders completely and turns out the layout is still losing proportions at some point.

**Big container:**

[image: big container image]

**Small container:**

[image: small container image]

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/s09rkwub/1/

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="rows fib">
    <div class="cols fill">
      <div class="rows fill">
        <div class="fr tl">3</div>
        <div class="fill cols">
          <div class="fc bl">4</div>
          <div class="fill rows">
            <div class="fill cols">
              <div class="fill tl fr">7</div>
              <div class="fc tr">6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="fr br">5</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fc tr">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fr br">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.rows {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.cols {
  flex-direction: row;
}
.rows,
.cols {
  display: flex;
  .fill {
    flex: 1;
  }
  > * { 
    outline: solid 1px rgba(127,127,127, 0.3);
  }
}
...
```

**Update:**
Working [demo](http://codepen.io/antraxis/pen/xEYXgR?editors=1100#0) with applied solution.

**Update 2**
Thanks to Your support guys. I could finish my fib spiral [codepen](http://codepen.io/antraxis/pen/xEYXgR).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

Add this to your code:

```
* {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
}
```

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s09rkwub/3/)

### Explanation

Two concepts to consider:

1. *An initial setting of a flex container is `flex-shrink: 1`*.

   This means that, by default, flex items are allowed to shrink below any defined `width`, `height` or `flex-basis`.

   To prevent this behavior use `flex-shrink: 0`.

   More details here: [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)

---

2. *An initial setting of a flex item is `min-width: auto`.*

   This means that, by default, a flex item cannot be smaller than the size of its content (regardless of `flex-shrink` or `flex-basis`).

   To allow flex items to shrink past their content use `min-width: 0` (row direction), `min-height: 0` (column direction), or `overflow: hidden` (other values also work, except `visible`).

   More details here: [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)

---

With the adjustment below, your flex items can shrink past the text you have in your divs, allowing the scaling to continue without any obstacles:

```
* {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a different approach than @Paul suggested and both answers solve the problem. Your response is more detailed so i will wait with marking an accepted answer. Thank you for the detailed review!

Comment: I checked proposed solution: turns out that only setting cells min-width/height to 0 solved the problem, without touching Shrink property :)

Comment: @DariuszSikorski, Yes, I figured `min-*` was likely all you needed. But I didn't have time to review your code line-by-line, so I threw `flex-shrink` in there, just in case (and as a general concept to be aware of). Nice design and structure, by the way.

Answer (score 5):

Taking `<div class="fr br">5</div>` as an example, it's min-width is 26px. Thus, scaling the spiral down to a level, where the mentioned div's height becomes less than 26px, it's getting distorted.

If you change the border width to 1px instead of 5px, you'll see, that suddenly, it's able to scale down to 18px perfectly fine and breaks in smaller sizes.

That's why you probably tried to reduce the border. However, the reason for the distortion is much simpler: You have content inside the divs and they do require some space (even if the font color is transparent). If you remove all the numbers from the div elements, you get the desired result. See the demo at https://jsfiddle.net/s09rkwub/2/

Comment: Awesome! I forgot this invisible letters. Thanks for the quick solution.

Comment: Hey, after reading the answers i decided to pick the second one as accepted since it allows me to leave text inside cells and stil make them shrink.