# Change the order of full width columns in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following grid:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">col-sm-6</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">col-sm-6</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">col-sm-12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/amApvk

It has the `.col-sm-12` block displayed under the first two items. What I want is to display the same column under the *first* column on *extra smal* screens.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">col-sm-6</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">col-sm-12</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">col-sm-6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Seems like I can't use push / pull classes with full width columns, so is it only JS left?

PS: The first item should go first on extra small screens too, so I can't change the order of the first two columns on extra small screens.

Comment: Go look up flexbox' `order` property.

Comment: @CBroe I need to cover IE too, also Bootstrap v4 is still an alpha.

Comment: I wasn't talking about BS4. And IE has decent enough support for this in all versions that any responsible developer would still support.

Comment: @CBroe, you was absolutely right to advice flexbox. The answer below provided a solution that worked as expected. Worked in IE 11 which is all I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve this with flexbox you can do the following:

Create a class modifier for Bootstrap's `row` class.

```
.row--flex {
  display: flex; /* Creates a flex container. */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Wrap columns, now flex-items. */
}
```

Since Bootstrap's  `col-*` classes already set a different `width` percentage for each viewport using media queries and our `flex-container` has `flex-direction: row;` by default, you will not need to define a `flex-basis` on `flex-items`, here's **[why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34355447/4305494)**.

---

Then you remove the floats, because they are not needed anymore:

```
.row--flex [class^="col-"],
.row--flex [class*="col-"] {
  float: none;
}
```

---

Finally you use a selector in the element with the `col-*` class you want to move.

We will use the class `col-order-*` as a selector.

Move the second column down changing its `order` property value to `1` and you're done.

> The CSS order property specifies the order used to lay out flex items
>   in their flex container.

The default `order` value in `flex-items` is `0`, that's why using any value higher than that will work.

**CSS:**

```
.col-order-1 {
  order: 1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row--flex">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">col-sm-6</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-order-1">col-sm-12</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">col-sm-6</div>
  </div>
```

---

### Code Snippet:

```css
.row--flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row--flex [class^="col-"],
.row--flex [class*="col-"] {
  float: none;
}
.col-order-1 {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row--flex">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">col-sm-6</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-order-1">col-sm-12</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">col-sm-6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Edit:

If you want this only applied to extra small screens, declare the `col-order-*` class inside a media query.

**Example:**

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .col-xs-order-1 {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

---

### Code Snippet:

```css
.row--flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row--flex [class^="col-"],
.row--flex [class*="col-"] {
  float: none;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .col-xs-order-1 {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row--flex">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">col-sm-6</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-order-1">col-sm-12</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">col-sm-6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I will try to implement it into my grid (that is a bit more complicated) and get back to you.

Comment: Worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @Deka87 You're welcome. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing some tests here, to tell you the truth I didn't knew it about this feature in bootstrap V3, but after a few minutes searching I've realised that the major point to achieve what you want is paying attention in the **HTML MARKUP**.

col-vp-push-x = push the column to the right by x number of columns, starting from where the column would normally render -> position: relative, on a vp or larger view-port.
col-vp-pull-x = pull the column to the left by x number of columns, starting from where the column would normally render -> position: relative, on a vp or larger view-port.

*vp = xs, sm, md, or lg*

*x = **1** thru **12*** 
In the example below, B comes before A like I said bellow, and that it only does the pushing or pulling on view-ports that are greater than or equal to what was specified. i.e. col-sm-push-5 will only push 5 columns on sm view-ports or greater. This is because Bootstrap is a "mobile first" framework, so your HTML should reflect the mobile version of your site. The Pushing and Pulling are then done on the larger screens.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4  col-xs-12">
        Content B
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4 col-xs-12">
        Content A
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4 col-xs-12">
        Content C
    </div>
</div>
```

See the demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/kL649qp0/1/

Also, I tried to follow your number of columns but the layout got messed due to the number exceed 12 columns.

*I hope it helps!*

Obs.: 
 1. (Desktop) Larger view-ports get pushed and pulled.
 
 2. (Mobile) Smaller view-ports render in normal order.
Source: http://www.schmalz.io/2014/10/08/Column-Ordering-in-Bootstrap/

Comment: That was the problem that the 3d column should span full width on all screen sizes, i.e. the total number of cols will always be more than 12.