# why is flex-basis size not being applied?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an input element which I want to grow and shrink using flex shrink but its flex-basis size is not being applied.

Here is my html:

```
<input type="text"/>
```

and my css:

```
input{
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 0 1 450px;
}
```

why is the basis size not being applied? it is getting set to a much smaller width than 450px.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/614abhj2/1/) is a fiddle with the example.

Comment: because it applies to a child of a flex box : https://jsfiddle.net/614abhj2/2/

Comment: `flex`, `flex-basis`, `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` are properties that apply  to *flex items* (the children of a flex container). For sizing a flex container, you can use `width`, `height`, `min-width`, `max-width`, `min-height` and `max-height`. More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have applied `display: flex` to the `<input>` element instead of a div.

The ideal way is to use a container/wrapper and then make the container `display: flex` & then control the input using `flex-basis` - [Here is your Fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/614abhj2/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container input { flex: 0 1 450px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to establish a **flex formatting context**.

> This is the same as establishing a block formatting context, except
>   that flex layout is used instead of block layout.

For properties like `flex-basis`, `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` to work, an element must participate in the flex formatting context.

> A flex item establishes a new formatting context for its contents. The
>   type of this formatting context is determined by its display value, as
>   usual. However, flex items themselves are flex-level boxes, not
>   block-level boxes: **they participate in their container’s flex
>   formatting context**, not in a block formatting context.

```js
var el = document.querySelector("input");
console.log("input width: " + el.offsetWidth + "px");
```

```css
.flex-container {  /* Flex formatting context, this makes the element a flex container */
  display: flex;
}
input {  /* Direct children of flex containers are now flex items */
  background-color: black;
  flex: 0 1 450px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <input type="text" />
</section>
```

---

[**Revised jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/x5bq6cdn/)

---

Source: *[W3C CSS Flexible Box Layout Module Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)*

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
    display:flex;
}

input{
  background-color: black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 0 1 450px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
```

check this

Comment: what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Apply flex properties to a input container rather than to the input.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.input-holder {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.input-holder input {
  flex: 0 1 450px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-holder">
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!