# Width of flex items is being reduced

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a navigation menu which will be scrollable horizontally in mobile. To do that I want to do it using `flexbox` but when I set the mobile view the width of the navigation items is reduced.

I tried using the `flex-grow` and `flex-basis` properties setting them to `1` and `0` respectively but it didn't work.

In this case I'm using dummy names for the navigation sections, but they can be of different length.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

[Codepen sample](http://codepen.io/abaracedo/pen/ENgarQ)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Keep in mind that an initial setting of a flex container is `flex-shrink: 1`.

This means that, by default, flex items are allowed to shrink. This prevents them from overflowing the container.

To disable this feature use `flex-shrink: 0`.

So, for your `li`, you can try this (shorthand version):

```
flex: 1 0 auto  (can grow, cannot shrink, initial main size based on content)
```

More details here: *[What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)*

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
min-width
```

or

```
max-width
```

instead