# Avoid squeezing of elements when using flex display

Tags: javascript, css, html, flexbox

I want to avoid squeezing of elements when using the below CSS code, especially for **Chrome browser, ver. 39**.

This CSS code works well on Chrome ver. 46. But I need to use old version like v.39 of Google Chrome. Because I use this version as a wrapper to create a desktop PC application.

Here is the squeezing effect which I want to avoid:

[image]

Here it looks fine:

[image]

```css
#bascket {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 52.9%;
  top: 14.72%;
  left: 0px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  outline: none;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div id="bascket">
  <div class="order-item">
    <div class="oi-p1">1</div>
    <div class="oi-p2">Item Name 1</div>
    <div class="oi-p3"></div>
    <div class="oi-p4">77</div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-item">
    <div class="oi-p1">1</div>
    <div class="oi-p2">Item Name 2</div>
    <div class="oi-p3"></div>
    <div class="oi-p4">77</div>
  </div>
  <div class="vertical-line-1"></div>
  <div class="vertical-line-2"></div>
</div>
```

This is a web app wrapped into a desktop application. And what i do here is just adding items to bascket area. I use this javascript code to add items:

```
var bascket = document.getElementById("bascket");
var item = document.createElement("DIV");
item.innerHTML = "...see the above full html code sample"
bascket.insertBefore(item, bascket.firstChild);
```

If I do this:

document.getElementById('bascket').style.height = '100%';

Then it is better, but this changes item display, and I lose the bottom which shows the last item , see this image:

[image]

I think I should play with height stretch and fit, but I cannot find how to do that

Comment: I have tried to make the parent element to have auto size, using this: height:auto; this will display the elements from bascket better, but then other problem will occur, and bascket will extend its content on other elements, and this mess the screen again :(

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow` properties apply only to flex items. You have them on the flex container.

The default setting is `flex-shrink: 1` regardless, so your flex items (the children of `#bascket`) have this setting and are allowed to shrink.

You can disable shrinking with `flex-shrink: 0` *on the flex items*.

More details here:

- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)

Comment: @Fed I think he means putting `flex-shrink: 0` on the children of `#basket`. Basket is the flex container, and as your code is now, flex-shrink/grow isn't doing anything.

Comment: @chazsolo Yes, you are right, I should put it on each children of #bascket... my mistake, that previously i tried to put on parent node #bascket and childrens of each item of #bascket, so it should be on childrens of #bascket, not children of children :)