# Control width of flex items arranged vertically in a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

I'm trying to achieve the effect where the boxes labeled "HALF", take up only 50% of the width (aka they share the first row evenly).

The base requirement is that they remain in a single container. Is this possible to achieve using flexbox?

I've tried playing around with `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis` but I'm afraid I'm not understanding how to make it work, or if it's even possible, given the single container requirement.

Consider this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GyXxT/270/

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.child {
  
  height: 200px;
}
.child.half {
  flex: 1 1 10em;
  color: green;
}

.child:not(.half) {

  flex-shrink: 2;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  color: purple; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child half">
    HALF
  </div>
  
  <div class="child half">
    HALF
  </div>
  
   <div class="child">
    FULL
  </div>
   <div class="child">
    FULL
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    FULL
  </div>
   <div class="child">
    FULL
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of `flex-direction: column`, you can try a *wrapping* flexbox using `flex-wrap: wrap`; and you can set:

1. `flex-basis: 50%` for the half width divs
2. `flex-basis: 100%` for the full width divs

See that I have thrown in `box-sizing: border-box` to adjust for the widths when using *flex-basis*.

See demo below:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.child {
  height: 200px;
}
.child.half {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  color: green;
}
.child:not(.half) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child half">
    HALF
  </div>

  <div class="child half">
    HALF
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    FULL
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    FULL
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    FULL
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    FULL
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a much simpler way, although only available for Firefox and Chrome : adding the following properties on the children will limit their size to fit their content :
`width: -moz-max-content` and `width: max-content`

Answer (score 8):

The flex sizing properties -- `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, `flex-basis` and `flex` -- work only along the *main axis* of the flex container.

Since your container is `flex-direction: column`, the main axis is vertical, and these properties are controlling height, not width.

For sizing flex items horizontally in a column-direction container you'll need the `width` property.

(Here's a more detailed explanation: [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276))

To achieve your layout with a single container, see [another answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41228469/3597276).

If you want to stay in column-direction, you'll need to wrap the `.half` elements in their own container.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
}
.container > div:first-child {
  display: flex;
}
.child.half {
  flex: 1 1 10em;
  color: green;
  width: 50%;
}
.child {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div><!-- nested flex container for half elements -->
    <div class="child half">HALF</div>
    <div class="child half">HALF</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">FULL</div>
  <div class="child">FULL</div>
  <div class="child">FULL</div>
  <div class="child">FULL</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks more reasonable than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

> The base requirement is that they remain in a single container.

That can also be done without `flexbox`, by simply float the 2 `half` elements

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 400px;
}
.child {
  height: 200px;
}
.child.half {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  color: green;
}
.child:not(.half) {
  width: 100%;
  color: purple; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child half">
    HALF
  </div> 
  <div class="child half">
    HALF
  </div>
  
   <div class="child">
    FULL
  </div>
   <div class="child">
    FULL
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    FULL
  </div>
   <div class="child">
    FULL
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this is true, and something I completely overlooked, the flexbox approach is closer to the desired effect. With 50% widths, when the screen is made smaller, at some point 50% is too small. The flexbox approach simply drops the second item down when it doesnt fit, which is the effect I want. Your approach could be made responsive with media-queries but flexbox suffices for me. Thanks, upvoted

Comment: @parliament Of course, and thanks ... note, by giving the `half` elements a min-width will do the same ... and combined with a media query, which both solutions need, you can have them all take full with when wrapped

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose is to hardcode the size in CSS units, or in percentages (which was mentioned the question), @kukkuz's solution is good as it is.

If you want to size element widths according to their own individual contents, then `align-tems: flex-start` or similar could do the job. It's possible to deal with the dimension perpendicular to that of the flex layout itself. See a tester on the bottom of the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) page

(Old question, but previous answers were incomplete, some are misleading)