# Using CSS flexbox grid for populating API data

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm making a node express website, for the news page I'm using data from news api (https://newsapi.org/) The data does appear on the page but it won't respond to CSS flexbox accordingly. My intention was, each `news-row` will look like a box containing image, headline, and brief content and the boxes should go like this :
box box box box
box box box box
box box box box

With the Scss below boxes appears like this:
box
box
box
box
box

```
    //scss file
    .news-container {
        background-color: $light-background;

        .news-tb {
            width: 350px;
            display: flex;

            .news-row {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }

        }
    }

   //ejs file
     <div class="news-container">
        <table class="news-tb">
            <% for(var i = 0; i < data.articles.length; i++) {  %>
                <tr class="news-row">
                    <td class="news-img"><img src="<%= data.articles[i].urlToImage %>"/></td>
                    <td class="news-title"><%= data.articles[i].title %></td>
                    <td class="news-content"><%= data.articles[i].content %></td>
                </tr>
            <% } %>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good attempt of you of using flexbox to address this problem. The one dilemma of flexbox is that it can be hard to use it with `table` since they're both different ways of displaying things. See also [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421512/why-does-flex-box-work-with-a-div-but-not-a-table).

**Using** `table` **solution** 
A workaround to just use `table` to achieve what you want is specifically set all the elements to `display: flex;` and use that. Here's a [CodePen example to do that](https://codepen.io/donroyco/pen/VGNmxO).

```
$light-background: #eee;

.news-tb {
  background-color: $light-background;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;

  tbody,
  tr,
  td {
    display: flex;
  }

  tbody {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .news-row {
    flex: 1 1 25%;
  }
}
```

**Using div solution** 
There's a solution that uses divs instead of `table`. Here's the [CodePen example](https://codepen.io/donroyco/pen/eLoBvG) for that. It's substantial shorter than the former solution and still it is showing valid HTML and CSS.

```
.news-tb {
  background-color: $light-background;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;

  .news-row {
    flex: 1 1 25%; 
  }
}
```

is only needed to make the 'rows' take 25 percent of the width.