# Why doesn't flex-grow: 1 work for a table in Safari?

Tags: html, css, html-table, safari, flexbox

Here's a snippet.

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

td,
th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

td:last-child,
th:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <h1>Table</h1>
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Foo</th>
        <th>Bar</th>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Baz</td>
        <td>Qux</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you run it in Chrome (and most browsers, fwiw), you get this:

[image: Chrome snippet]

But in Safari 13.0.2 on macOS it's like this:

[image: Safari snippet]

Comment: Which version of Safari and on what OS?

Comment: Did you set width 100%?

Comment: did you try `table-layout:fixed` on table?

Comment: @Paulie_D it's Safari 13.0.2 on macOS

Comment: @Awais so with `width: 100%` it works but I'd like to only use flexbox. `flex-grow: 1` should work

Comment: Rather than `flex-grow:1` what happens if you use `flex:1`?

Comment: @Paulie_D just tried now, nothing changed. Afaik `flex: 1` is just the sorthand for `flex: 1 1 0`, which includes `flex-grow: 1`

Comment: @TemaniAfif tried to set `table-layout: fixed` now, nothing changed.

Comment: @PaulBerg Not always - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386244/what-does-flex-1-mean

Comment: I think that you may find some guidance in this post: [**Why does flexbox work with a div, but not a table?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41421512/3597276) (Note: Focus on the answer by @Oriol. Although my answer is currently most highly voted, it amounts to just a hack for that particular question. Oriol's answer really explains the problem.)

Comment: Thank you @Michael_B that thread explains the problem and the possible solutions perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Michael_B, I now understand that the table works in a rather peculiar way with flexbox styling.

- [Why does flex-box work with a div, but not a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421512/why-does-flex-box-work-with-a-div-but-not-a-table)

It seems I must use `width: 100%` instead of `flex-grow: 1`. It's not the end of the world, since the table is at the deepest level in the dom hierarchy, but it's still a bummer.