# Table with FlexBox - TD height issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a table where

- first column's `<td>` has `divs` with `display:flex`
- second columns's `<td>` also has `divs` with no `display` property set. So the two divs stack upon each other (intended).

**Problem** : Since the second column's `td` has `divs` stacked upon each other its height increases due to which the first columns's `td` looks small.

**Expected** : Both `td` should have same height.

**Tried** : On first columns `td`

- `height:100%`
- `align-items:stretch`
- `position`

Cannot give a fix height as the data is dynamic, second columns `td` can have more divs.

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="d-flex">
          <div>Data</div>
          <div>1-1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div>Data</div>
          <div>1-2</div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="d-flex">
          <div>Data</div>
          <div>2-1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div>Data</div>
          <div>2-2</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: table has issues with flexbox check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421512/why-does-flex-box-work-with-a-div-but-not-a-table

Comment: Interesting,  so seems like my best bet is to drop `flex` on `table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably do not need to reset display for td,div can instead be reset to inline.

Eventually, you may use white-space on td to keep the (inline)div on a single line.

Example with inline div.

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.d-flex >div{
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="d-flex">
          <div>Data</div>
          <div>1-1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div>Data</div>
          <div>1-2</div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="d-flex">
          <div>Data</div>
          <div>2-1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div>Data</div>
          <div>2-2</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```