# How can I reset width for items in CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

We have a legacy section of tiled items that were done with Flexbox.  The container of the items is a `ul`:

```
ul.icon-grid {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 list-style: none;
 padding-left: 0;
}
```

And then the items inside are `li`:

```
.icon-swatch__wrapper {
   width: 180px;
   height: 110px;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 12px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 10px;
 }
```

I had to use a width and height since the tiles have varied content and I needed them to be the same size.  Obviously, if I could use css grid I'd have no such problem.

So I am trying to add a scss block inside a `@supports` for grid, which although it works the fixed width of the items is throwing off the grid gutters.

```
@supports (display: grid) {
  ul.icon-grid {
   display: grid;
   grid-gap: 10px;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0;
   .icon-swatch__wrapper, li {
     margin: 0;
     width: auto;
   }
  }
}
```

I tried using `width: auto` as you see to remove the previously used `width: 180px` for the old flexbox version, but the tiles do not properly size to the grid.

If I *remove* the `width: 180px` from the flexbox version, the grid version looks perfect.  But then if someone has a browser that supports flex but not gris, it looks terrible.

How can I basically "remove" the `width: 180px`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `width: unset;` within the `@supports grid` block.

Answer (score 1):

With flexbox you need to define the size of flex items. You can use `width`, `height` and `flex-basis`.

With Grid, the approach is different. You can size the items at the container level. No need to define a size on the items.

```
 ul.icon-grid {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 180px);
   grid-auto-rows: 110px;
   grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I know how to size the things in Grid, my issue is the same items need to be sized in Flexbox. Using` flex-basis:180px` does not make the items uniform widths in the flexbox version.

Comment: Can you post a working demo? There are several possible reasons for the problem you describe. For one, see ***The `flex-shrink` Factor*** section here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34355447/3597276