# Fixed width child is shrinking in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using `display:flex` for the first time.

You find a codepen here: https://codepen.io/chrispillen/pen/GEYpRg

```css
.node:not(.branch) {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.node.branch,
.node.branch .body {
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.node.branch .leaf {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.node.branch .body {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.node.branch .body .tribe {
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.node.branch .body .subnodes {
  padding-top: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="node"></div>
<div class="node branch">
  <div class="leaf"></div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="tribe">TRIBE</div>
    <div class="subnodes">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="leaf"></div>
</div>
```

The "tribe" element doesn't remain with a width of 100px.

Everything else works as supposed. Can I force it somehow? And by the way: is flex the true reason for this behavior?

Comment: See this section ***The `flex-shrink` factor*** in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Flexbox items have [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) parameter with default of `1`. This means that in case your flexbox container don't have enough space its items will shrink.

To disable this behaviour for flexbox item set `flex-shrink: 0`.

Demo:

```css
.node:not(.branch) {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.node.branch,
.node.branch .body {
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.node.branch .leaf {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.node.branch .body {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.node.branch .body .tribe {
  width: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* new */
  background: blue;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.node.branch .body .subnodes {
  padding-top: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="node"></div>

<div class="node branch">
  <div class="leaf"></div>

  <div class="body">
    <div class="tribe">TRIBE</div>

    <div class="subnodes">
      <div class="node"></div>
      <div class="node"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="leaf"></div>
</div>
```