# Chrome does not expand flex parent according to children's content

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I need to display several boxes next to each other. Each box has a variable number of child items. The parent should expand according to the space that the child items are taking up. It is important that the items have fixed width. I'm using flexbox for layout. It should look like this:

[image]

I wrote a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Vz3VO85wJ58KYODLbaGN?p=preview) to illustrate.

The problem: Chrome does not expand the parent when the children take up more space. The child items are displayed beyond the parents' boundaries and appear in a neighbouring parent, resulting in this mess:

[image]

Ironically, if you open the Plunkr in IE 11 or Edge, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a code snippet:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.parent {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
}

.items span {
  flex-basis: 25px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h4>Parent 1</h4>
  <div class="items">
    <span>i1</span>
    <span>i2</span>
    <span>i3</span>
    <span>i4</span>
    <span>i5</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <h4>Parent 2</h4>
  <div class="items">
    <span>i1</span>
    <span>i2</span>
    <span>i3</span>
    <span>i4</span>
    <span>i5</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <h4>Parent 3</h4>
  <div class="items">
    <span>i1</span>
    <span>i2</span>
    <span>i3</span>
    <span>i4</span>
    <span>i5</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <h4>Parent 4</h4>
  <div class="items">
    <span>i1</span>
    <span>i2</span>
    <span>i3</span>
    <span>i4</span>
    <span>i5</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <h4>Parent 5</h4>
  <div class="items">
    <span>i1</span>
    <span>i2</span>
    <span>i3</span>
    <span>i4</span>
    <span>i5</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <h4>Parent 6</h4>
  <div class="items">
    <span>i1</span>
    <span>i2</span>
    <span>i3</span>
    <span>i4</span>
    <span>i5</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: using width instead of flex-basis works

Comment: This is a known bug occurring in nested flex containers. See the "Browser Bugs" section in the top answer in the duplicate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Chrome.

In this section of code:

```
.items span {
  flex-basis: 25px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

... Chrome is not respecting the fixed 25px width. Or, at least, the container is not recognizing the space. It looks like the container is being sized before all item calculations are factored in.

The simple workaround is to use `width` instead of `flex-basis`.

```
.items span {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 25px;
 }
```

[revised demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/r5ZHClFuPB27hLMPtMzg?p=preview)

---

**UPDATE**

Bug Report

> [**Flex-basis is being ignored when sizing nested flex containers.**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=464210)
>
> *"Yeah this is kind of a sucky consequence of a bug we have, perhaps combined with an unfortunate spec consequence..."*
>
> *"When the outer flexbox finds the desired size of the inner flexbox, it asks for its max-content size (see LayoutFlexibleBox::computeInnerFlexBaseSizeForChild). But here's where the bug comes in, the max-content size does not take `flex-basis` into account, only width properties/actual content. That's why adding an explicit width fixes the bug."*

Comment: Then Firefox suffer from the same bug :)

Comment: Yes, this happens in chrome, firebox and safari... Beware: I believe the bug might not always happen and two identical elements with identical styles might end-up looking different. For instance, modifying the styles on chrome dev tools I ended up with a good looking element but when copying its style and content to the actual source the bug spoiled it. Even downloading the correct-looking source and opening it in a new tab would look incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `inline-flex` instead of `flex`, also commented out some unwanted flex stylings please refer here,

```css
/* Styles go here */
body {
  /* display: flex; */
  overflow: scroll;
}

.parent {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.items {
  /* display: flex; */
}

.items span {
  flex-basis: 25px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h4>Parent 1</h4>
  <div class="items">
    <span>i1</span>
    <span>i2</span>
    <span>i3</span>
    <span>i4</span>
    <span>i5</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <h4>Parent 2</h4>
  <div class="items">
    <span>i1</span>
    <span>i2</span>
    <span>i3</span>
    <span>i4</span>
    <span>i5</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <h4>Parent 3</h4>
  <div class="items">
    <span>i1</span>
    <span>i2</span>
    <span>i3</span>
    <span>i4</span>
    <span>i5</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <h4>Parent 4</h4>
  <div class="items">
    <span>i1</span>
    <span>i2</span>
    <span>i3</span>
    <span>i4</span>
    <span>i5</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <h4>Parent 5</h4>
  <div class="items">
    <span>i1</span>
    <span>i2</span>
    <span>i3</span>
    <span>i4</span>
    <span>i5</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS doesn't support `//` line comments, only multiline `/* */`. Edited your answer to fix broken CSS :)

Comment: This also changes desired layout. `body`'s content should not wrap.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this out

Use 
box-sizing : border-box;  for parent element and using width to maintain the width of each element

https://plnkr.co/edit/3p8PwmLtHYozEFveRvTX

```
/* Styles go here */

body {
  display: flex;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.parent {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing : border-box;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
}

.items span {
  width: 25px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <h4>Parent 1</h4>
    <div class="items">
      <span>i1</span>
      <span>i2</span>
      <span>i3</span>
      <span>i4</span>
      <span>i5</span>
      <span>i1</span>
      <span>i2</span>
      <span>i3</span>
      <span>i4</span>
      <span>i5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <h4>Parent 2</h4>
    <div class="items">
      <span>i1</span>
      <span>i2</span>
      <span>i3</span>
      <span>i4</span>
      <span>i5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <h4>Parent 3</h4>
    <div class="items">
      <span>i1</span>
      <span>i2</span>
      <span>i3</span>
      <span>i4</span>
      <span>i5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <h4>Parent 4</h4>
    <div class="items">
      <span>i1</span>
      <span>i2</span>
      <span>i3</span>
      <span>i4</span>
      <span>i5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <h4>Parent 5</h4>
    <div class="items">
      <span>i1</span>
      <span>i2</span>
      <span>i3</span>
      <span>i4</span>
      <span>i5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <h4>Parent 6</h4>
    <div class="items">
      <span>i1</span>
      <span>i2</span>
      <span>i3</span>
      <span>i4</span>
      <span>i5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes! That works! Could you please update your answer with what changed (i.e. apply `box-sizing: border box;` to flex parent and remove `flex-shrink: 0;` from child)? It's easier for other to see the fix this way, without comparing every line of code.

Comment: On closer look, it breaks the fixed width of 25px for each item... Any clue?

Comment: .items span {
 width : 25px; 
}  using width:25px maintains the width of each item. I will update the answer with what solved the issue

Comment: `box-sizing` has nothing to do with this