# why min width is needed for flex item inside a flex container to encapsulate flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is the code snippet of code:

```css
.row-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 60px;
}

.row {
  flex-basis: 30px;
  background-color: coral;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-container">
  <div class="row">1</div>
  <div class="row">2</div>
  <div class="row">3</div>
</div>
```

After googling i found that if i use **min-width: 30px** instead of **flex basis** in the flex items then

**row-container width is equal to the total width of the row ie around 90px**

, but id i only use **flex-basis in flex items** then the row-container does not **encapsulates it children and the children over flows**.
Please let me know the reason for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome does not expand flex parent according to children's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482350/chrome-does-not-expand-flex-parent-according-to-childrens-content)

Comment: this is actually considered as a bug.