# Is there a way to replace the calc part from "flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px)" with other property?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following element:

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
   <div style="flex 1 1 calc(50% - 20px);" [repeated-n-times]> <!-- I don't want to use calc() here. But I'm looking for the same effect. -->
      <!-- some other markup -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Basically, I want to get rid off the `calc` part from `flex-basis` property. The last one from shorthand syntax.

Why? As you may know, IE11 is having some issues with `calc` in `flex-basis` property, on other side, we are using `@angular/flex-layout` module in our application, and we're looking for a workaround to make the layout looks (well, partially) good in IE11.

Is this doable?

Comment: Maybe try to give it something like `flex: 1 1 auto` or `flex: 1 1 45%` . You can also check this article https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of IE's flex bugs, so if you use the longhand `flex-basis`, `calc()` will work fine.

```css
div > div {
  background: lightgray;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
   <div style="flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);"> test
   </div>
   <div style="flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);"> test
   </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment

It is stated in the comment that `@angular/flex-layout` merges longhand flex into shorthand, so in that case one of these 3 options could help

- tell Angular to not merge (if possible)
- add a class and set its CSS to `flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px) !important;`
  <sub>*The `!important` is needed to override the inline style*</sub>
- use `width: calc(50% - 20px);` <sup>Note 1</sup>

---

<sub>Note 1</sub>

Based on how you actually use `flex-basis`, in many cases `width` does the same.

Here is a great answer explaining their differences:

- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352140/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-basis-and-width)

---

Update 2

If you can drop the `flex-grow: 1`, you can simply do this

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
  <div style="flex: 0 1 50%; margin: 0 10px; background: lightgray;"> test
  </div>
  <div style="flex: 0 1 50%; margin: 0 10px; background: lightgray;"> test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but as I said we're using `@angular/flex-layout`, which breaks up the things. It always merges element styles to a shorthand notation.

Comment: @vitozev Updated my answer

Comment: @vitozev Updated my answer again