# Input element's width behaviour is mysterious

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two input elements in a flexbox:

```
<div style="display: flex; width: 200px; background: black; padding: 2px">
  <input style="flex: 1" type="text" />
  <input style="flex: 1" type="text" />
</div>
```

([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7rw5mxkf/))

I want those to get the width of 200px evenly shared. They aren't however. Instead, they have have some mysterious default size. They don't listen to `min-width` either. They do listen to `width` though, so this does the desired thing:

```
<div style="display: flex; width: 200px; background: black; padding: 2px">
  <div style="flex: 1">
    <input style="width: 100%" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div style="flex: 1">
    <input style="width: 100%" type="text" />  
  </div>
</div>
```

([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsv18r3a/))

My question: why? And is this defined somewhere for some reason?

**EDIT:** This is what Chrome's inspector gives me:

[image]

**EXTRA QUESTION:**

As kukkuz pointed out, `min-width` *is* heeded - but only when the `input`s are direct children of the flex container. Otherwise, they again like to be broader:

```
<div style="display: flex; width: 200px; background: black; padding: 2px">
  <div style="background: red; padding: 2px">
    <input style="flex: 1; min-width: 0" type="text" />  
  </div>
  <div style="background: red; padding: 2px">
    <input style="flex: 1; min-width: 0" type="text" />  
  </div>
</div>
```

([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qaek5p5x/1/))

Bizarre. Is there a way to make this work without restorting to a `width: 100%`?

**EDIT:**

There is a way without resorting to a `width: 100%`: A nested flexbox. ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ntnwzmy/))

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 200px; background: black; padding: 2px">
  <div style="background: red; padding: 2px; flex: 1; display: flex; min-width: 0">
    <input style="min-width: 0; flex: 1" type="text" />  
  </div>
  <div style="background: red; padding: 2px; flex: 1; display: flex; min-width: 0">
    <input style="min-width: 0; flex: 1" type="text" />  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to avoid setting `width: 100%` on the `input`? ... If so, why?

Comment: I sometimes like to get the bottom of things. It's more a curiosity-driven question at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Input element's width behaviour is mysterious
>   My question: why? And is this defined somewhere for some reason?

There is nothing mysterious here. An `input` element without a set `width` get its size from its [`size` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-size), which defaults to `20`.

Based on your 2nd fiddle, if you remove `width: 100%` and set the `size` to `5`, you'll see it changes

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 200px; background: black; padding: 2px">
  <div style="flex: 1">
    <input style="" type="text" size="5" />
  </div>
  <div style="flex: 1">
    <input style="" type="text" size="5" />  
  </div>
```

Since the `size` attribute is based on *n* amount of character, it will be difficult to use it to match a parent's set `width`, so either use the CSS property `width` or one of the Flexbox properties `flex-grow`/`flex-basis` (nesting them included) to make them *...get the width of 200px evenly shared*

---

> EXTRA QUESTION:
>   As pointed out, `min-width` is needed - but only
>   when the `input`s are direct children of the flex container.
>   Otherwise, they again like to be broader.
>   Bizarre.

Still nothing strange (or bizarre), as when they aren't flex items (children of a flex container), they yet again become standard `input` elements and my first explanation applies.

> Is there a way to make this work without resorting to a width: 100%?

Yes, as you suggest your self, nest Flexbox so the `input`s become flex items, though it appears unnecessary to do that when you simply can drop their parents (the extra `div` wrappers).

---

Based on the given comments, the `min-width: 0` does work because a flex items default `flex-basis` is `auto`, which the specs. translate to:

> [***`auto`***](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#valdef-flex-basis-auto)
>
> When specified on a flex item, the `auto` keyword retrieves the value
>   of the main size property as the used `flex-basis`. If that value is
>   itself `auto`, then the used value is `content`.

Here is a great answer (where the above comment is taken), that explain `flex-basis` a little deeper

- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352140/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-basis-and-width)

Comment: Ok, that explains why inputs are special. I doesn't yet explain why a `min-width: 0` as a flex child makes it ignore the `size` attribute whereas as a non-flex child it has no effect.

Comment: @John See my last comment below _kukkuz_ answer

Comment: I read that, but: If that was true than either `size` shouldn't matter when it isn't a flex child or `min-width: 0` shouldn't have any effect when it is a flex child.

Comment: @John I guess you might misunderstood, it is the exact opposite.

Comment: Let's say a `input` element isn't a flex child. Then it's `min-width` defaults to zero as you say in the comment. Yet it clearly has a minimum width determined by the size. That means that the `min-width` property isn't what's causing the minimum-width behavior. If that's the case, then why is `min-width: 0` having an effect when it *is* a flex child?

Comment: Or more simply: Do you know any way to make `input`s lose their minimum width without resorting to a flex box? If not, then clearly something is missing in the picture, right?

Comment: @John Why `min-width` works on `input` being a flex items is because the _width_ is set to `flex-basis: auto`, hence override the `size`, and then the `min-width: 0` does its job.

Comment: @John _any way to make inputs lose their minimum width without resorting to a flex box?_ change its `size` value or use `width`

Comment: @John Be aware, form elements aren't what standard HTML elements are, so you can't apply standard HTML element's logic on them

Comment: @John What do you wan't to achieve with _...make inputs lose their minimum width_ ?

Comment: Nothing, that was just a way to clarify what I still thought was mysterious. I think your 4th last comment is what I needed, but I only have my phone right now... will think about this in an hour.

Comment: Ok, to this 4th-last comment: `flex-basis: auto` overrides the `size`, but why doesn't `width: auto` do the same thing when not a flex child?

Comment: @John Because the default of `width` is `auto`, hence the `size` is used, so bottom line, if not a _width_ is set, the `size`kicks in

Comment: That would mean that the `auto` for `flex-basis` and the `auto` for `width` mean different things, correct?

Comment: @John Not in itself as both says _size me based on content_, but a flex item also has `min-width: auto`, which makes all the difference since flex items have a different behavior. The linked post describes this very well.

Comment: Ok, this article says that `width` and `flex-basis` are different when `flex-basis` is `auto`. I still can't [get an `input` to fill it's container without using either `width: 100%` or a flex box](https://jsfiddle.net/tLyouu3t/3/) - but perhaps some things are not for man to know...

Comment: @John As I stated in my answer, the only way, if not Flexbox or `width`, is to elaborate with its `size`

Answer (score 1):

Input elements have a default *computed* width due to the user agent / browser. So it responds to `width`.

You can set `min-width: 0` - see demo below:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  background: black;
  padding: 2px;
}

div input {
  min-width: 0;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: You're right. I thought I tried that. At least Chrome doesn't tell me about that though - the inspector doesn't show where the width is coming from in that case.

Comment: Added what's in the computed section in this case. As you see, it's greyed out which means Chrome can't tell me the rule the width is coming from. Super-confusing.

Comment: I have a slight variation of the problem coming up as `inputs` are often nested in `divs` - thought it was too similar to warrant a new question.

Comment: @John `flex: 1` (and `min-width: 0` on the flex child) only applies to *flex children* (*flexbox* behaviour only applies to direct children of the flexbox container).... see https://jsfiddle.net/9cgd78uh/

Comment: But that's using `width: 100%`. The `min-width: 0` really shouldn't have had anything to do with the flexbox and it's only necessary for `input` children. In your last fiddle, you can just remove it as simple `div`s don't need it.(And `flex: 1` was missing but doesn't make a difference.)

Comment: `min-width: auto` is the default for *flex children* which means it takes the width of the content (here the *default* width of the `input`)... when we set it to `min-width: 0` the flexbox can shrink beyond the *default*

Comment: Right, `min-width` *is* necessary on the divs if the contents are an `input` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s06L5sut/)). I still don't get why a `min-width: 0` works on an input when it's a direct child of a flex container but not when it's in a div that is itself already correctly sized.

Comment: `min-width` works with `flex: 1` here... if its nested, the intrinsic size of the `input` may cause an *overflow* as it is *not* a flex child... that's how things work in css I guess :)

Comment: @John `min-width` on a direct child of a flex container, a flex item, defaults to `auto`, but on a non flex item it defaults to `0`, hence you won't see any difference on regular items