# Element loses all of its width as soon as it breaches parent's width

Tags: html, css

Why does the element in the following example collapse in on itself?

Even though the element is set to `box-sizing: border-box`, its border will remain, yet the element loses all of its width as soon as it breaches the perimeter of its parent.

What is going on?

[***CODEPEN***](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/yzKvao)

```js
let   t = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at velit commodo, facilisis ex vitae, viverra tellus.'
let   c = 0
const e = document.getElementById('statement-container')
const i = setInterval(function(){
  if (t[c] !== ' ') e.innerHTML += t[c]
  else e.innerHTML += '&nbsp;'
  c++
  if (c >= t.length) clearInterval(i)
}, 100)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing : border-box;
}

body {
  width       : 100vw;
  height      : 100vh;
  margin      : 0;
}

section:first-child {
  width       : 40vw;
  height      : 100vh;
  position    : relative;
  left        : 30vw;
  display     : flex;
  border      : solid blue 1px;
}

#statement-container, #caret {
  height      : 15%;
  position    : relative;
  top         : calc(50% - 7.5%);
}

#statement-container {
  z-index     : 98;
  font-family : beir-bold;
  font-size   : 6.5vmin;
  color       : red;
}

#caret {
  z-index     : 99;
  width       : 10%;
  border      : solid green 5px;
  background  : orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <div id="statement-container"></div>
    <div id="caret"></div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: I made the text longer to fully reproduce it, and rolled back the edits of @DemoDemo, because they basically broke the behavior that the question seems to be about...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the element in the following example collapse in on itself?

As you are using *[`display: flex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)* on the `section`, its children becomes flex items.

Flex items has a property called *[`flex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property)*, which is shorthand for *[`flex-grow`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-flex-grow), [`flex-shrink`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-flex-shrink) and [`flex-basis`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-flex-basis)*, which control how the item size itself based on available space and its content.

The `flex-basis`, in this case in a *[flex row direction](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-direction-property)*, which is the default, controls the items width.

The default value is `flex: 0 1 auto` which mean it won't *grow* (`0`) beyond its content, it is allowed to *shrink* (`1`) and its *flex-basis* (`auto`) size it according to its content.

Since in this case *[`width` and `flex-basis`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352140/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-basis-and-width)* do the same, here giving the `caret` an set width of 3%, it will keep that width as long as there is enough space, and won't grow, but when the space becomes negative (items won't fit anymore) it will start shrink down to its content width, which it doesn't have any, hence its content area collapse completely.

---

One solution would be to tell it to not be allowed to shrink, by changing `flex-shrink` to `0`.

```js
let   t = 'Nothing is completely perfect.'
let   c = 0
const e = document.getElementById('statement-container')
const i = setInterval(function(){
  if (t[c] !== ' ') e.innerHTML += t[c]
  else e.innerHTML += '&nbsp;'
  c++
  if (c >= t.length) clearInterval(i)
}, 100)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing : border-box;
}

body {
  width  : 100vw;
  height : 100vh;
  margin : 0;
}

section:first-child {
  width    : 40vw;
  height   : 100vh;
  position : relative;
  left     : 30vw;
  display  : flex;
  border   : solid blue 1px;
}

#statement-container, #caret {
  height      : 15%;
  position    : relative;
  top         : calc(50% - 7.5%);
}

#statement-container {
  font-family : beir-bold;
  font-size   : 15vmin;
  color       : red;
}

#caret {
  flex-shrink : 0;                             /* added  */
  width       : 5%;
  border      : solid green 5px;
  background  : orange;
}
```

```html
  <section>
    <div id="statement-container"></div>
    <div id="caret"></div>
  </section>
```

Comment: `flex: 0 1 auto` as a default value is obviously browser specific, correct?

Comment: @LGSon: Why `#statement-container` did not shrink?

Comment: @Duannx Because a flex item by default will never be smaller than its _content_, which `statement-container` has and `caret` has not. If you add `min-width: 0` to the `statement-container` rule, which defaults to `auto`, it will also shrink, but overflow the text, which `overflow: hidden` would prevent, and can be used instead of `min-width: 0`.

Comment: @LGSon: If you add content `#caret`. It still shrink and `#statement-container` still does not.

Comment: @Duannx If you show me a fiddle, or similar, that doesn't work as you expect, I'll let you know what does what.

Comment: @LGSon: Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abowj8jo/1/). My expectation is two items shrink together, not only `#caret`

Comment: @Duannx That is because it add a `&nbsp;` (`else e.innerHTML += '&nbsp;'`) between the characters instead of a space in the script, where the `caret` has space ... this one use space: https://jsfiddle.net/abowj8jo/3/

Comment: @LGSon: Yeah. Pertfect. Thank you very much. Upvoted your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can set `min-width: 10%;` the element calculated width after going outside the parent is 0 because the statement container is taking 100% of the available space. As stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/min-width):

> The min-width CSS property sets the minimum width of an element. It
>   prevents the used value of the width property from becoming smaller
>   than the value specified for min-width.

```js
let   t = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at velit commodo, facilisis ex vitae, viverra tellus.'
let   c = 0
const e = document.getElementById('statement-container')
const i = setInterval(function(){
  if (t[c] !== ' ') e.innerHTML += t[c]
  else e.innerHTML += '&nbsp;'
  c++
  if (c >= t.length) clearInterval(i)
}, 100)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing : border-box;
}

body {
  width  : 100vw;
  height : 100vh;
  margin : 0;
}

section:first-child {
  width    : 40vw;
  height   : 100vh;
  position : relative;
  left     : 30vw;
  display  : flex;
  border   : solid blue 1px;
}

#statement-container, #caret {
  height      : 15%;
  position    : relative;
  top         : calc(50% - 7.5%);
}

#statement-container {
  z-index     : 98;
  font-family : beir-bold;
  font-size   : 6.5vmin;
  color       : red;
}

#caret {
  z-index     : 99;
  width       : 10%;
  border      : solid green 5px;
  background  : orange;
  min-width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <div id="statement-container"></div>
    <div id="caret"></div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: interesting. i'll upvote your answer, simply because it's additive, but it doesn't really answer the question. the question was **why** does it happen?

Comment: i completely understand `min-width`, but what i don't understand is that the element's own width is set to 10% of **its parent** width. so, again, the question is why does the element lose its width if the widthof the parent element doesn't change?

Comment: The caret height is 15% of the parent height, and that 15% its always available. The width in this case its calculated with `width = "parent width " -
 "statement container width"`and the result will be 0 after the "statement container width" reach the "parent width". To check this try to switch the position of the caret with the statement container, the caret width will be always 10% because nothing BEFORE is taking space.

Comment: nono, i completely understand what is happening. What I'm asking is why does the width of `statement-container` effect its width at all since its width is set to **`10%` of its parent's width**?? I'm assuming it has something to do with the way `flex` elements are regulated or behave.

Comment: It's because of `display:flex` of the parent. Non-wrappable (by default) flex container tries to fit all its children (which become flex items) into a row inside it, shrinking some of these items if necessary as much as their `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` values allow. By default, `flex-shrink` is `1` and `flex-basis` is `auto`, which basically means "by content". Since `.caret` has no content, it shrinks to zero.

Comment: @Ilya Streltsyn: I encourage you to post that as a separate answer.

Comment: @BoltClock Since this answer doesn't correctly explains why, I posted an answer, and first now read up fully on these comments :) ... and there it was, though I laid mine out some more

Answer (score -3):

```js
let   t = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at velit commodo, facilisis ex vitae, viverra tellus.'
let   c = 0
const e = document.getElementById('statement-container')
const i = setInterval(function(){
  if (t[c] !== ' ') e.innerHTML += t[c]
  else e.innerHTML += '&nbsp;'
  c++
  if (c >= t.length) clearInterval(i)
}, 100)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing : border-box;
}

body {
  width  : 100vw;
  height : 100vh;
  margin : 0;
}

section:first-child {
  width    : 40vw;
  height   : 100vw;
  position : relative;
  left     : 30vw;
  display  : flex;
  border   : solid blue 1px;
}

#statement-container, #caret {
  height      : 15%;
  position    : relative;
  top         : calc(50% - 7.5%);
}

#statement-container {
  z-index     : 98;
  font-family : beir-bold;
  font-size   : 6.5vmin;
  color       : red;
}

#caret {
  z-index     : 99;
  width       : 10%;
  border      : solid green 5px;
  background  : orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <div id="statement-container"></div>
    <div id="caret"></div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: i'm confused. that doesn't do anything differently than the example i provided?

Comment: @BoltClock whatever you edited didn't seem to have any effect?

Comment: @Anthony: All I did was fix the incorrect snippet formatting. Like you, I am completely baffled as to what Demo Demo is trying to convey here.

Comment: @BoltClock is there any way to get rid of this answer since it's absolutely useless and the other answer is a lot more useful if anybody stumbles upon this thread?

Comment: @Anthony: If Demo Demo doesn't respond after some time I'll delete it.

Comment: @BoltClock perfect. at least the other question is at the top now

Comment: i have change just css not much more

Comment: i have just change this css   section:first-child {height:auto or height:100vw}