# Why does Chrome not expand an outer grid when the inner grid does

Tags: css, google-chrome, grid-layout

I have a nested grid layout made with capital G Grid styles.  In the nested grid there is an image set to 100% width, which causes its height to grow proportionally and its immediate parent grid to expand vertically.  However, in Chrome the grand-parent grid does not grow.

I've mocked up the situation here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vpEVZj?editors=1100

The first, `.single-grid` displays fine, but the second `.outer-grid` does not.

Is this a bug in Chrome or am I missing something?

**Edit: Today, neither the demo, nor my application are showing this issue.  Maybe it's just a humpday issue.**

Comment: Can you show what the expected behavior is? I just viewed it in Chromium and Firefox with the same results, so it's not specific to Chrome.

Comment: Works fine in FF and Edge. Looks like a bug in Chrome. Probably another issue with nested containers, which [Chrome also struggles with in flexbox on occasion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34355447/3597276).

Comment: @jhpratt The expected behaviour is for the bottom example to function like the top example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the reason is, but you can get the expected behavior in Chrome by changing `grid-template-columns: auto` to `1fr`:

```
.outer-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Not changing anything for me.

Comment: This solved the problem for me using the codepen demo.