# Make images stretch to container's edge

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have a container that has a width of 75vw and an image gallery inside that container. What I am looking to do is have the images always be the right size to stretch out to the ends of the container no matter the screen size. Is there a way to do this. Would Calc in CSS work? If so how could I use it? Thanks.

Website [here](https://1080benchmarks.github.io/projects/portfolio2/)

```css
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<!--Content Start-->
<div class="content">
  <!--Navigation & Header & Messy-->
  <div class="top">
    <div class="left">
      <h1>Jude Wallach</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Gallery Start-->
  <div class="gallery">
    <figure>
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/464x464" class="galleryitem"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/464x464" class="galleryitem"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/464x464" class="galleryitem"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/464x464" class="galleryitem"></a>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the [`flex` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to set the [flex basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis). I've set each `<figure>` to 47.5% so that there's always 5% between them, and also set a 5% top margin to simulate a grid with equal space around each box. I also set each image to fill 100% of its parent's width.

```
figure {
  flex: 0 0 47.5%;
  margin: 5% 0 0;
}

figure img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

I'd also recommend using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) so that the two columns stack on smaller devices.
Below, I've used a sort of "mobile first" pattern.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #909090;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  max-width: 75vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 255, .5); /* just for demo purposes */
}

.top {
  text-align: center;
}

#head_links {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#head_links li a {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.gallery figure {
  margin: 5% 0 0;
}
.gallery figure img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .top {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align:left;
  }
  .left, .right {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
  }
  #head_links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  #head_links li:not(:first-child) {
    margin: 0 0 0 1em;
  }
  .gallery {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-flow:wrap;
  }
  .gallery figure {
    flex: 0 0 47.5%;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .gallery figure {
    flex: 0 0 30%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .gallery figure {
    flex: 0 0 21.25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="left">
      <h1>Jude Wallach</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <ul id="head_links">
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <figure>
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/464x464">
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/464x464">
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/464x464">
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/464x464">
      </a>
    </figure>
        <figure>
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/464x464">
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/464x464">
      </a>
    </figure>
        <figure>
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/464x464">
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/464x464">
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/464x464">
      </a>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

To calculate the basis percentage, I use this formula:

> (100 / items per row) - ( (gap percentage desired * gaps per row) / items per row)

For example, for three items per row:

> (100 / 3) - ( 5 * 2 / 3 ) = **30%**

For four items per row:

> (100 / 4) - ( 5 * 3 / 4 ) = **21.25%**

---

In your case, flex shorthand might be unnecessary and regular old `width` would probably work just as well. For more information see [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352140/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-basis-and-width)

Also useful: [Understanding Flexbox: Everything you need to know](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-flexbox-everything-you-need-to-know-b4013d4dc9af) - particularly the part about [flex item properties](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-flexbox-everything-you-need-to-know-b4013d4dc9af#c67f).

Comment: Thanks, so if I wanted three images to fit I would style figure with flex: 0 0 33% right? And then adjust the margin. I always use flexbox but never quite understood the flex property so I'm going to try and learn it.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. I edited that into my example. I also find this to be a helpful reference: [Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).