# css flexbox 3-column layout where first is fixed width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to better understand flex box css and have a main layout for all pages. It is 3 columns where the first column is fixed width and the others can be any size so long as all 3 take up 100% width.

I believe the problem is in `.col` class but unsure how to set the 1st column and let the other grow. Thank you.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: See *"The `flex-shrink` factor"* here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B Very helpful, that clarifies things. Ty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to specify a fixed width to the first one and then set `flex:1` to the other so they take the remaining space and fill 100% of the container space:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}


.col {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}
.col:first-child {
  width: 100px; /* Or a percentage value */
  flex:initial;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I knew it was a simple fix. Thank you! If I had 1 more upvote on the question I could give you one.