# setting initial width of items in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having a problem with flexbox, I'm trying to get my first `.cell1` to take on the width of the 3 items inside it so it should be 300px wide so I have set this to `flex: 0 0 auto` and I have set `.cell2` to `flex: 1` so it takes up the remaining space but instead of doing this it seems to overlap `.cell1` and I'm not sure why?

How can I get `.cell1` to take on the width of the 3 items inside it and `.cell2` to take the remaining width?

```css
.wrap {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.cell1{
  display:flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.cell2{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background: #ff0000;
}
.item1{
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background: #ff0000;
}

.item2{
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background: #0000ff;
}

.item3{
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background: #ff00ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="cell1">
    <div class="item1">
    item 1
    </div>
    <div class="item2">
    item 2
    </div>
    <div class="item3">
    item 3
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cell2">
  cell2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `width` instead of `flex-basis`. This is a known bug that you can read more about here :

[What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352140/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-basis-and-width) *(At the end of the accepted answer by @Michael_B)*

> Bug affecting all major browsers, except IE 11 & Edge:
>
> **flex-basis ignored in a nested flex container**. **width works**. A problem
>   has been found when sizing flex items in a nested flex container.

```css
.wrap {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.cell1{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.cell2{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background: #ff0000;
}
.item1{
  width:100px;
  background: #ff0000;
}

.item2{
  width:100px;
  background: #0000ff;
}

.item3{
  width:100px;
  background: #ff00ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="cell1">
    <div class="item1">
    item 1
    </div>
    <div class="item2">
    item 2
    </div>
    <div class="item3">
    item 3
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cell2">
  cell2
  </div>
</div>
```