# What is the difference between the flex and height properties?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given the following example, both will fill out the center to consume the remaining space in the page, given the page is using `flex`. I am leaning towards using the css property `flex` vs `height` in the body. Is there a difference that needs to be considered when applying one over the other?

**CSS**

```
.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
}

.body {
  flex: 1; // vs height: 100%;
}

.footer {
  height: 40px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
   <div class="header">Sample Header</div>
   <div class="body">Sample Body</div>
   <div class="footer">Sample Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code is perfectly fine. You can use flex and height, it's okay. I guess this is the only way to give specific height while using flex. Otherwise, everything works on percentage. I mean in a responsive way. So if you need to make this responsive, you need to code again to do this so. That's the only disadvantage. Otherwise, it's fine

Comment: Did you even tested the both variants? [height](https://jsfiddle.net/9z2upukx/1/) vs [flex](https://jsfiddle.net/6Ljo3ny4/)

Comment: Yes I have tested both, they both work perfectly, I was asking which was better, if there was a difference, and what is better practise, functionally they both work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set an element to `flex: 1`, that breaks down to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

In a column-direction container (like you have), the flex properties above apply vertically. This means that `flex-basis` and `height` are equivalent properties.

```
flex-basis = height (in a column-direction container)
```

There is an obvious difference between `flex-basis: 0` and `height: 100%`. It's the same difference as `height: 0` and `height: 100%`.

In your situation, where there is a `.header` and a `.footer` consuming 140px of vertical space, setting the middle item (`.body`) to `height: 100%` would normally cause an overflow.

But since an initial value of a flex container is `flex-shrink: 1`, flex items are permitted to shrink, and this wouldn't happen. However, it's still sloppy and imprecise coding, in my view.

By setting `.body` to `flex: 1`, you're setting the height to `0`, but also allowing it to consume free height with `flex-grow: 1`. I would say, in this case, that this solution is more efficient.

---

More details:

- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)
- [§ 7.1.1. Basic Values of `flex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common)

Answer (score 2):

There is a huge difference between flex and height.

First to answer your question.

1. Height 100% doesn't use the remaining space. It will use all the spaces of parent,  in your case if page dom is `height 200px;` then body will also be `height: 200px;`.
2. Flex will be correct solution here to fill up the space (`flex: 1`).

   Flex is more than filling the space, its more of a layout and it has influences on its child, how they position and align.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
   display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.body {
    display: flex;
  flex-direction:  column;
    height: 80vh;    
      align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;  

}

.footer {
  height: 40px;
    display: flex;
     align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
   <div class="header">Sample Header</div>
   <div class="body">Sample Body</div>
   <div class="footer">Sample Footer</div>
</div>
```