# Adding scroll to flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have an app that takes up 100% width/height of the screen. There is a fixed width sidebar on the left, and a flexible size div on the right. The div on the right has a fixed height toolbar on the bottom and a flexible height box above it. How can I make sure the toolbar on the bottom scrolls horizontally when overflowed, and the sidebar on the left scrolls vertically when overflowed?

[image]

```css
html,
body,
.my-app {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.my-app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.sidebar {
  background: brown;
  width: 300px;
}

.map-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.map {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

.toolbar {
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-app">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <p>
      Sidebar fixed width of 300px;
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="map-container">
    <div class="map">
      <p>
        Map should grow to fill available space horizontally and vertically
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="toolbar">
      <table class="large-table">
        <tr>
          <td>Content should scroll and be 300px</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tvsgthb7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html, body, .my-app {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.my-app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.sidebar {
  background: orange;
  /* width: 300px; */
  flex: 0 0 300px; /* makes 300px width inflexible with flex-shrink: 0 */
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar > p {
  height: 1000px;
}

.map-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0; /* allows flex item to shrink past its content size */
}

.map {
  background: aqua;
  flex: 1;
}

.toolbar {
  height: 300px;
  background: lightgreen;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-app">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <p>
      Sidebar fixed width of 300px;
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="map-container">
    <div class="map">
      <p>
        Map should grow to fill available space horizontally and vertically
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="toolbar">
      <table class="large-table">
        <tr>
          <td>Content should scroll and be 300px</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tvsgthb7/3/)

More information here:

- [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)
- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)