# Flex-basis not working when setting it for a Select dropdown

Tags: css, flexbox

Have a flex container with flex-direction: row. And each of those individual columns are again flex containers with a flex-direction: column.

Have a few form-inputs in the flex row, but when I try to give the Location select a initial flex-basis: 250px, it doesn't work and it applies it vertically.

But, I can't find a way to make it apply it horizontally.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column input-container location">
              <label for="location">Location</label>
              <select name="location">
                <option *ngFor="let location of locations" [value]="location.locationId">
                  {{location.locationName}}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

//styling

```
.row {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        // flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .column {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .location select {
    flex-basis: 250px;
}
```

Here's the link to it running in a stackbliz, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vr4cya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `flex-basis` property applies to the *main axis* of a flex container.

This means that in `flex-direction: row` it controls width, and in `flex-direction: column` in controls height.

If you're in `flex-direction: column` and need to set a flex item's width, then use the `width` property.

```
.additional-assignment[_ngcontent-c0] .location[_ngcontent-c0] select[_ngcontent-c0] {
    /* flex-basis: 250px; */
    width: 250px; /* new */
```

More details:

- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)
- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)