# Unexpected behavior controlling overflow in Flexbox code

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

I'm trying to create a layout like this:

[image]

The *top div* has a fixed height of 100px, the *bottom div* has a fixed height of 50px and the div in between use the available space of the window.

Here's the code:

```css
html body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.topRow {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.bottomRow {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 50px;
}

.content {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 2px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="topRow">Top div</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>
      <p>First column</p>
    </div>
    <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; overflow-y: scroll; background-color: azure">
      <p>first row</p>
      <p>2 row</p>
      <p>3 row</p>
      <p>4 row</p>
      <p>5 row</p>
      <p>6 row</p>
      <p>7 row</p>
      <p>8 row</p>
      <p>9 row</p>
      <p>10 row</p>
      <p>11 row</p>
      <p>12 row</p>
      <p>13 row</p>
      <p>14 row</p>
      <p>15 row</p>
      <p>16 row</p>
      <p>17 row</p>
      <p>18 row</p>
      <p>19 row</p>
      <p>20 row</p>
      <p>3-1 row</p>
      <p>3r2 row</p>
      <p>3r3 row</p>
      <p>3r4 row</p>
      <p>3r5 row</p>
      <p>3r6 row</p>
      <p>3r7 row</p>
      <p>last row</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>The last column</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottomRow">Bottom div</div>
</div>
```

If I run this code in Chrome (Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)) in Windows 10 x64 it works as I expect however when I run it in Firefox (Version 63.0.1 (64-bit) (Official Build)) in the same Windows 10 it doesn't work as expected.

Here's the result in Firefox:

[image]

As you can see the top div don't have a 100px height and the bottom div is out of the browser's window. Also the white column ignore the *overflow-y: scroll*

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong that it doesn't work in Firefox?

PD: I've also tested the same code in Firefox 57 and I get the same result as in Firefox 63.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `flex-shrink`

An initial setting of a flex container is [**`flex-shrink: 1`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink). This means that flex items can shrink in order to prevent overflow of the container. You can disable this feature with `flex-shrink: 0`.

```
.topRow {
   height: 100px;
   flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

OR

```
.topRow {
   flex: 0 0 100px; /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
}
```

For more details, see the ***The `flex-shrink` factor*** section in my answer here:

- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)

---

### `min-height: auto`

An initial setting of flex container is `min-height: auto`. This means that flex items cannot be smaller than the height of their content. To override this setting use `min-height: 0` or `overflow: auto`.

```
.content {
   overflow: auto;
}
```

See this post for more details:

- [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)

To understand why your layout worked in Chrome but not Firefox, see the ***Browser Rendering Notes*** section in my answer to the post above.

---

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/12m4qLyt/)

```css
 .flex-grid {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 100vh;
 }

 .topRow {
   background-color: gray;
   height: 100px;
   flex-shrink: 0; /* new */
   border: 2px solid black;
 }

 .bottomRow {
   background-color: cadetblue;
   border: 2px solid black;
   /* height: 50px; */
   flex: 0 0 50px; /* new */
 }

 .content {
   background-color: orange;
   border: 2px solid black;
   flex: 1;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: space-between;
   overflow: auto; /* new */
 }

 body {
   margin: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="topRow">Top div</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>
      <p>First column</p>
    </div>
    <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; overflow-y: scroll; background-color: azure">
      <p>first row</p>
      <p>2 row</p>
      <p>3 row</p>
      <p>4 row</p>
      <p>5 row</p>
      <p>6 row</p>
      <p>7 row</p>
      <p>8 row</p>
      <p>9 row</p>
      <p>10 row</p>
      <p>11 row</p>
      <p>12 row</p>
      <p>13 row</p>
      <p>14 row</p>
      <p>15 row</p>
      <p>16 row</p>
      <p>17 row</p>
      <p>18 row</p>
      <p>19 row</p>
      <p>20 row</p>
      <p>3-1 row</p>
      <p>3r2 row</p>
      <p>3r3 row</p>
      <p>3r4 row</p>
      <p>3r5 row</p>
      <p>3r6 row</p>
      <p>3r7 row</p>
      <p>last row</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>The last column</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottomRow">Bottom div</div>
</div>
```