# flexbox min-width failing in IE and Edge

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, microsoft-edge

I have some table that set width for  elements so some columns will have at least some percent of a width of the container.

I want to use flexbox to center this table and set the minimum-width for it.

**The goal is to have centered table with some minimum width for which some columns will have the same width (same ratio).**

If some cells have longer texts then I don't care if ratio will broke (width of this column will be bigger then other). I just care that it has nice and same width of columns  for common case (small amount of text data in cells)

I was able to came up with solution that works on Firefox and Chrome ([link](https://codepen.io/mpawelski/pen/WYWraY)).

But for Edge and IE11 the table stretch as if it was not in flex container (try to comment `display: flex;` on Firefox or Chrome and the result is stretched table like on Edge.

Also it looks that *sometime* setting columns work ([link2](https://codepen.io/mpawelski/pen/QJPNQw)). But I don't see the pattern of when it break in Edge/IE11.

Here is more production example that I want to achieve (works in Chrome/Firefox, stretch in Edge/IE11): ["production" table example](https://codepen.io/mpawelski/pen/PxgNxv).

Any ideas how to achieve what I want on Edge/IE11? (I put in bold what I want to achieve).

It would be good if I could keep using flexbox container (it might require more changes in my codebase) but I think I will be fine with deleting `style=width:p%` from `<col>` if that's necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `min-width` rule is apparently being ignored in Edge / IE11.

There's an equivalent command that seems to work.

Instead of:

```
.inner {
    min-width: 800px
}
```

Use:

```
.inner {
    flex-basis: 800px; /* 1 */
    flex-shrink: 0;    /* 2 */
}
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xQegoN)

---

notes:

1. `flex-basis` is a substitute for `width`, in this case (see: [`flex-basis` vs `width`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276))
2. `flex-shrink: 0` ensures `flex-basis` / `width` cannot decrease below 800px (hence, both rules together emulate `min-width`)