# CSS avoid position above another using Flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to position three columns, I am using flex, but I need to avoid that one div be positioned above another div.

How can it be done ?

In my attempt the third div is above the second div.

This is my attempt:

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-flow: row nowrap;" ng-repeat="hour in Hours">
  <div style="width:10%">
    <span><i class="fa fa-clock" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{Hours.movieSession}}</span>
  </div>
  <div style="width:10%">
    <img src="img/3d_i.svg" ng-if="Hour.IMAX == 1 && Hour['3D'] == 1">
    <img src="img/i2.svg" ng-if="Hour.IMAX == 1 && Hour['3D'] == 0">
    <img src="img/3d.svg" ng-if="Hour['3D'] == 1 && Hour.IMAX == 0">
  </div>
  <div style="width:10%">
    <a href="{{Hour.SiteHref}}" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-dollar-sign"></i> Buy
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want your div as columns, then how can they be above or below ? They can be by side as they are now.

Comment: your flex childs are in row. How can they be above an other flex child? To the question -> You can use [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/order) for your flex-childs to change their order

Comment: Please remove the `width` property and check again

Comment: Thank you @KuldeepBhimte removing width do the trick.

Comment: Thank you @d-h-e order works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With flex, you probably want to use `flex-basis` instead of `width`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis

https://gedd.ski/post/the-difference-between-width-and-flex-basis/

[What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352140/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-basis-and-width)

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-flow: row nowrap;" ng-repeat="hour in Hours">
  <div style="flex-basis:10%">
    <span><i class="fa fa-clock" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{Hours.movieSession}}</span>
  </div>
  <div style="flex-basis:10%">
    <img src="img/3d_i.svg" ng-if="Hour.IMAX == 1 && Hour['3D'] == 1">
    <img src="img/i2.svg" ng-if="Hour.IMAX == 1 && Hour['3D'] == 0">
    <img src="img/3d.svg" ng-if="Hour['3D'] == 1 && Hour.IMAX == 0">
  </div>
  <div style="flex-basis:10%">
    <a href="{{Hour.SiteHref}}" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-dollar-sign"></i> Buy
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes @ritaj the second collumns can vary of width or have no element so i want to let always the same width for the second collumn

Comment: You always want the same width for the second column? Then use `flex: 0 0 10%` to always have it 10% width. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex