# Flex item overflowing when using flex-basis

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to create spacers between elements using the `flex-basis` property. Doing this will allow me to maintain space between elements regardless of the ´flex-direction`.

This works pretty well when using `flex-direction: column`, but when using `flex-direction: row` (default value), the last item in the row is overflowing, and cropped.

[image]

Full working example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NVxaoy

```css
input {
  margin: 0;
}

.field {
  display: flex;
}

.field.stacked {
  flex-flow: column;
}

.label {
  display: flex;
}

.spacer.x1 {
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 8px;
}

.spacer.x2 {
  background: red;
  flex: 0 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Horizontal</h1>
<div class="field">
  <label class="label">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <div class="spacer x1"></div>
            <div class="text">Apple</div>
        </label>
  <div class="spacer x2"></div>
  <label class="label">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="spacer x1"></div>
            <div class="text">Banana</div>
        </label>
  <div class="spacer x2"></div>
  <label class="label">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="spacer x1"></div>
            <div class="text">Orange</div>
        </label>
</div>
<h1>Stacked</h1>
<div class="field stacked">
  <label class="label">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <div class="spacer x1"></div>
            <div class="text">Apple</div>
        </label>
  <div class="spacer x2"></div>
  <label class="label">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="spacer x1"></div>
            <div class="text">Banana</div>
        </label>
  <div class="spacer x2"></div>
  <label class="label">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="spacer x1"></div>
            <div class="text">Orange</div>
        </label>
</div>
```

Is there a solution or work around to this?

Comment: This is a known bug occurring in nested flex containers. See the "Browser Bugs" section in the top answer in the duplicate.

Comment: @Michael_B I added one more duplicate. Is that the same issue you mean?

Comment: @LGSon, it's a useful answer (like all posts of @Oriol). But in the end, the problem is just a bug, so a long, technical explanation with lots of spec references is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I am honestly not sure why this cropping occurs but you can work around it by changing your spacers to use `width` instead of `flex`

```css
input { margin: 0 }

.field {
  display: flex;
}

.field.stacked {
  flex-flow: column;
}

.label {
  display: flex;
}

.spacer.x1 {
  background: green;
  width: 8px;
}
.spacer.x2 {
  background: red;
  flex: 0 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Horizontal</h1>
<div class="field">
  <label class="label">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div class="spacer x1"></div>
    <div class="text">Apple</div>
  </label>
  <div class="spacer x2"></div>
  <label class="label">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div class="spacer x1"></div>
    <div class="text">Banana</div>
  </label>
  <div class="spacer x2"></div>
  <label class="label">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div class="spacer x1"></div>
    <div class="text">Orange</div>
  </label>
</div>

<h1>Stacked</h1>
<div class="field stacked">
  <label class="label">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div class="spacer x1"></div>
    <div class="text">Apple</div>
  </label>
  <div class="spacer x2"></div>
  <label class="label">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div class="spacer x1"></div>
    <div class="text">Banana</div>
  </label>
  <div class="spacer x2"></div>
  <label class="label">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div class="spacer x1"></div>
    <div class="text">Orange</div>
  </label>
</div>
```