# How do I mix width and percentage(left/right) in flex layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I have 3 blocks, that I need to:

- The first block needs to be 200px wide and touch the left side.
- The second block is right after the first block and its right edge is at exactly 50% width of its container
- The third block just takes over whatever the space is left.

I made something similar in some game engine:
[image]

But how can I achieve it with css?

I don't want to nest the inner divs because they're playing the same role.

---

I tried this but it doesn't work :(

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper > * {
  height: 300px;
  display block;
}

.wrapper > *:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: salmon;
  width: 200px;
}

.wrapper > *:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: khaki;
  right: 50%;
}

.wrapper > *:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: violet;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <pre>
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
  </pre>
  <pre>
    left: 200px;
    right: 50%;
  </pre>
  <pre>
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/gocelehuxi/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `flex: 0 0 50%` to the *third child* which means the element would *not* grow, shrink and will always occupy half the width of the flexbox container.

Now to allow the *second child* to occupy the remaining space left by the other two elements you can set `flex-grow: 1` and set `min-width: 0` (allows it to shrink further than its intrinsic width - note that default `min-width` is auto for a *flex item*).

See demo below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper > * {
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
}

.wrapper > *:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: salmon;
  width: 200px;
}

.wrapper > *:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: khaki;
  flex-grow: 1; /* grow width automatically if needed */
  min-width: 0; /* allow shrinking below default width */
}

.wrapper > *:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: violet;
  flex: 0 0 50%; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <pre>
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
  </pre>
  <pre>
    left: 200px;
    right: 50%;
  </pre>
  <pre>
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, it makes so much sense to adapt the middle element instead of the third one... and one more thing I'm not very clear, is there any difference between `flex: 0 0 200px` and `width: 200px` ?

Comment: Nvm I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352140/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-basis-and-width , thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

   body{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
   }

    .wrapper, .wrapper-1 {
      width: 50%;
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
    }

    .wrapper > *, .wrapper-1 > * {
      height: 300px;
      margin: 0;
      display: inline;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .wrapper > *:nth-child(1) {
      background-color: salmon;
      flex-basis: 200px;
    }

    .wrapper-1 > *:nth-child(1) {
      background-color: violet;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
    }

    .wrapper > *:nth-child(2) {
      background-color: khaki;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
    }

    .wrapper > *:nth-child(3) {
      background-color: violet;
     flex: 1 auto;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <pre> flex-basis: 200px;
  </pre>
  <pre> flex: 1 1 auto;
  </pre>
  
</div>
<div class="wrapper-1">
    <pre>flex: 1 1 auto;  </pre>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not really what I wanted... the first and second block add together should be 50% wide :/

Comment: @HaoWu Made some changes. Need to split the page into two wrappers. Both containing 50% of the width. Now you can handle contents the way you like :)