# How the width of a inline-flex div is decided?

Tags: html, css

for an inline-flex div, the width is depending on its children elements' width. Here is the code, I don't set the parent div with specified width. So, it is decieded by inside elements.

For the three children elements, one is with `width:50%`, others are `width:50px`, but the final width for 2 is 31.75, how does it come?

```
    <div style="display: inline-flex;flex-wrap: nowrap;">
        <div style="width:50%;color:red">1</div>
        <div style="width:50px;color:blue">2</div>
        <div style="width:50px;color:black">3</div>
        <span>hello</span>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a step by step illustration to understand what the browser is doing:

```css
div div {
 outline:1px solid green
}
```

```html
<p>The browser will first ignore the width:50% and use auto instead</p>
<div style="display: inline-flex;flex-wrap: nowrap;border:2px solid red">
    <div style="width:auto;color:red">1</div>
    <div style="width:50px;color:blue">2</div>
    <div style="width:50px;color:black">3</div>
    <span>hello</span>
</div>
<p>Now that we have the width of the parent, it will no more change and we resolve width:50%</p>
<div style="display: inline-flex;flex-wrap: nowrap;border:2px solid red">
    <div style="width:50%;color:red">1</div>
    <div style="width:50px;color:blue">2</div>
    <div style="width:50px;color:black">3</div>
    <span>hello</span>
</div>
<p>all the div will shrink because there is not enough space for them (50% + 50px + 50px + hello > 100%). A shrink that you can disable if you use flex-shrink:0 and you will have overflow</p>
<p>Only "hello" will not shrink because a flex item cannot shrink past its content size</p>
<div style="display: inline-flex;flex-wrap: nowrap;border:2px solid red">
    <div style="width:50%;color:red;flex-shrink:0;">1</div>
    <div style="width:50px;color:blue;flex-shrink:0;">2</div>
    <div style="width:50px;color:black;flex-shrink:0;">3</div>
    <span>hello</span>
</div>
```

For more detail about the shrink algorithm if you want to understand the calculation:

[How flexbox calculates flex-item's width if no flex-basis or width are set?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56580551/8620333)

[Why is a flex item limited to parent size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49492208/8620333)

To understand why "hello" will not shrink:

[Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/8620333)

---

The purple area you see in the dev tools is the width before the shrink effect. You can notice it's equal to 50px for the 2nd and 3rd div