# How to make image take maximum space in flex container?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I need to make an image take the maximum size (taking max width or max height) in a flex container.

Since the parent container doesn't have a fixed width and height, I can't use `max-width` and `max-height` and `flex:1` is not working either.

Here is an example of the problem : https://jsfiddle.net/vb26u0e5/2/

I would like the image to take automaticaly all the available green space (remove the `width: 40px;` line 20).

```css
#mainContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
}

#imageContainer {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: green;
}

#image {
  width: 40px;
}

#previous,
#next {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: purple;
}

#title,
#footer {
  text-align: center;
}

#title {
  background-color: blue;
}

#footer {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
  <div id="title">TITLE</div>
  <div id="imageContainer">
    <div id="previous">&lt;</div>
    <img id="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" />
    <div id="next">&gt;</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
#image {
  width: 40px;
  flex-grow: 1; /* new */
}
```

Normally, you would be able to use `flex-basis` (which is equivalent to `width`, in this case), and do some like this:

```
#image {
  flex: 1; /* fg:1, fs:1, fb:0 */
}
```

OR

```
#image {
  flex: 1 0 40px; 
}
```

However, some browsers have a bug which causes them to ignore `flex-basis` in *nested* flex containers. So the `width` / `flex-grow` combination is a clean workaround.

For more details see the "Browser Bugs" section in my answer here:

- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)

---

The demo below covers the issue answered above, plus height issues – aspect ratio and vertical scroll – by wrapping the image in a div and using absolute positioning and `object-fit` on the image.

Tested in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

```css
#mainContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
}

#imageContainer {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: green;
}

#image {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#previous,
#next {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: purple;
}

#title,
#footer {
  text-align: center;
}

#title {
  background-color: blue;
}

#footer {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
  <div id="title">TITLE</div>
  <div id="imageContainer">
    <div id="previous">&lt;</div>
    <div id="image">
      <img src="https://pixabay.com/get/52e3dc454f50a414f6d1867dda6d49214b6ac3e45657744e7d2b72dc90/oldtimer-4396528_1920.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="next">&gt;</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqjwp2o9/)

Comment: The ```width:40px```was to remove, just to show the green space. It almost works on Firefox (but height is too large and cause a scroll). It doesn't work at all on Chrome.

Comment: Understood. I just used it to demo `flex-basis`. You can remove it. I'm also posting a full demo, that solves for width and height.

Comment: It's working great ! Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: @JeanBlaguin, generally speaking, try to avoid making images into flex / grid items. Browsers can't yet reliably handle images in a flex / grid formatting context (risk of buggy behavior is high). Wrap the image in a div, making the div the item, and keeping the image in a block formatting context.

Answer (score 0):

use `object-fit` property to specify how the image should be resized to fit its container. I have set it to `object-fit: cover` which  will cut off the sides of the image, preserving the aspect ratio, and also filling in the space. Also use `flex-grow:1` to fill the 'green' space.

```css
#mainContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
}

#imageContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: green;
}

#image {
  object-fit: cover;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#previous,
#next {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: purple;
}

#title,
#footer {
  text-align: center;
}

#title {
  background-color: blue;
}

#footer {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
  <div id="title">TITLE</div>
  <div id="imageContainer">
    <div id="previous">&lt;</div>
    <img id="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" />
    <div id="next">&gt;</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tested this solution? it does not seem to work.

Comment: @Dementic I used a dummy image URL. I have changed it to the right one.

Comment: it dosent work as expected, if you try to resize the output window, it does not auto-fit to the container: https://jsfiddle.net/1p6n3w9j/4/

Comment: @Dementic thanks for pointing out the flaw. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Still dosent work, the image is now cut off on the width.

Comment: it will. `object-fit` will fit the image to fill the container in a variety of ways such that it will preserve the aspect ratio. i have already mentioned it in the answer.

Comment: Click `Run Code Snippet` to see the result yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197938/discussion-between-soothran-and-dementic).

Answer (score 0):

You can `calc` the width based on Vertical Width (100vw) & remove the padding of your PREV/NEXT
Something like this?

```css
#mainContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
}

#imageContainer {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: green;
}

#image {
  width: calc(100vw - 50px);
  height: 100vh;
}

#previous,
#next {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: purple;
}

#title,
#footer {
  text-align: center;
}

#title {
  background-color: blue;
}

#footer {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
  <div id="title">TITLE</div>
  <div id="imageContainer">
    <div id="previous">&lt;</div>
    <img id="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" />
    <div id="next">&gt;</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The Header and footer content is variable so I'm afraid it's not an option. I'd like the image to size automatically