# Absolutely positioned container not expanding width to fit flexbox content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I have a `flexbox` inside of an absolutely positioned parent `div`. I expect the `flexbox` to have a `computed width`, causing the parent div to expand, but this doesn't happen.  The parent div has some width, but it is not wide enough to accommodate the flexbox.

Given that the flexbox has four children, each with `flex-basis: 100px`, and `flex-shrink: 0`, I'd expect the flexbox to have a width of `400px`, causing the parent div to expand to `400px` of content width. It is instead expanding to a seemingly arbitrary `255px`.

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  background: #EEE;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="flex-child">One</div>
    <div class="flex-child">Two</div>
    <div class="flex-child">Three (really really long)</div>
    <div class="flex-child">Four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found setting `min-width: max-content;` on the `.flex` container works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works in Edge.

It doesn't work in Firefox and Chrome.

This appears to be a bug with `flex-basis` in those browsers.

There's a simple workaround: Instead of `flex-basis`, use `width`.

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
  /* flex: 1 0 100px; */

  width: 100px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;

  background: #EEE;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="flex-child">One</div>
    <div class="flex-child">Two</div>
    <div class="flex-child">Three (really really long)</div>
    <div class="flex-child">Four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xu6wake1/)

Also see:

- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140)

Comment: I'd like the flexbox to "grow" if the parent happens to be wider than the flexbox (as is expected behavior based on `flex: **1** 0 100px`).

Comment: Add `flex-grow: 1` to the `.flex-child` class. https://jsfiddle.net/k0gxLw3z/

Comment: `flex-basis` and `width` are interchangeable (in row-direction). It appears that `flex-basis` isn't being handled properly by Chrome and FF. So use `width` instead. The other flex properties -- `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` -- can still be used in their longhand form.

Comment: works great. Just after I spent an hour converting it tables.. now I'll convert it back. Update your answer with `flex-grow: 1` and I'll happily accept! Thank you.

Comment: Just out of curiosity -- is there any way for me to edit your snippet to test things? I know you provided a jsFiddle, but sometimes I encounter answers with snippets only and it's infuriating how I can't fiddle with the snippets.

Comment: You can edit my answer and then edit the snippet. And then not save the changes. But that's a bit cumbersome. That's why I always include a jsFiddle in my answer, so that others can play with the code. You can also copy snippet code into the jsfiddle editor, which I do a lot.

Comment: Yes, jsFiddle is much nicer. I do the same -- but find it cumbersome to c+p into various js/css/html sections. By the way, please add a `;` after `width: 100px`, it's breaking your snippet. I tried to edit but it wanted 6 character change.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to make the elements fit the absolutely positioned element was to change the following line

```css
.flex-child {
    flex: 1 1 100px;
    ...
}
```

After that the `.flex` element occupied the `.parent` element and if I increased any widths the red area expands.

Does that work for you?

Comment: The question is asking for the parent to expand to the width of the content, not the other way around.

Comment: Because this has `flex-shrink: 1`, it doesn't enforce the minimum width of `100px` per flexchild. As noted above, I'd like this minimum width to be used to stretch the width of the parent (if the parent is not wide enough).