# Why can't this flexbox be scrolled?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to understand why the following code does not creates a scrollable flexbox.

```js
var firstData = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
FillDiv();
FillDiv();

$("button").on('click', function() {
 FillDiv();
});

function FillDiv() {
 var newData = GetData();
  
  for (i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
    $(".wrapper").append('<div>Test</div>');
  }
}

function GetData() {
  return firstData;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.wrapper div {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 1%;
  }

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
</div>

<button>
NEXT
</button>
```

However, the following example does:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://as1.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/12/43/28/500_F_212432820_Zf6CaVMwOXFIylDOEDqNqzURaYa7CHHc.jpg" alt="">
<img src="https://as1.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/12/43/28/500_F_212432820_Zf6CaVMwOXFIylDOEDqNqzURaYa7CHHc.jpg" alt="">
<img src="https://as1.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/12/43/28/500_F_212432820_Zf6CaVMwOXFIylDOEDqNqzURaYa7CHHc.jpg" alt="">
<img src="https://as1.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/12/43/28/500_F_212432820_Zf6CaVMwOXFIylDOEDqNqzURaYa7CHHc.jpg" alt="">
<img src="https://as1.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/12/43/28/500_F_212432820_Zf6CaVMwOXFIylDOEDqNqzURaYa7CHHc.jpg" alt="">
<img src="https://as1.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/12/43/28/500_F_212432820_Zf6CaVMwOXFIylDOEDqNqzURaYa7CHHc.jpg" alt="">

</div>
```

Why does the scroll breaks when I add width and height in first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flex-shrink: 0` to your Test divs. Flex items are set, by default, to `flex-shrink: 1`, which enable them to shrink in order to prevent an overflow of the container.

For more details see *"The `flex-shrink` factor"* section in my answer here:

- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)

---

The problem addressed above doesn't exist in your second example (with the images) because another default setting of flex items is `min-width: auto`. This means that flex items cannot, by default, be smaller than their content. If you override this default with `img { min-width: 0 }`, you'll get the same behavior as in your first example.

For more details about the flex minimum sizing algorithm see:

- [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)