# What property controls width when flex-direction is set to "column"?

Tags: css, flexbox

While i set `flex-direction: column` and `align-items:flex-start`(or any value except default which is called "stretch"), Which auto assigned CSS property controls *width* of the flex items?

I know that `flex-basis` controls height when I set `flex-direction:column` (since the main-axis is top to bottom). But I really wonder that which property does it control "width" of that flex item in this situation?

Comment: Erm `width` - actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the specification and following [the Cross Size Determination](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#cross-sizing):

> Determine the used cross size of each flex item. If a flex item has align-self: stretch, its computed cross size property is auto, and neither of its cross-axis margins are auto, the used outer cross size is the used cross size of its flex line, clamped according to the item’s used min and max cross sizes. **Otherwise, the used cross size is the item’s hypothetical cross size.**

Wihout using stretch you will clearly fall into the *hypothetical cross size*

> Determine the hypothetical **cross size** of each item by performing layout with the used main size and the available space, **treating auto as fit-content.**

Then we can also read:

> cross size
>
> cross size property
>
> The width or height of a flex container or flex item, whichever is in the cross dimension, is that box’s cross size. Its cross size property is thus **either its width or height property**, whichever is in the cross dimension.

So you simply define the width with the *width* property when dealing with a column direction and if it's `auto` it will compute to `fit-content`

More detail around `fit-content` here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#fit-content-size

Answer (score 2):

That would be the CSS [`width`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276) property.