# flex and white-space: nowrap; child won't respect width

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow, nowrap

Take a look at this snippet: Childs are 50% of parent height and the content overflows thank to the childs are `inline-block` and the parent has `white-space: nowrap`

```css
div.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 480px;
  margin: 24px 0;
}

div.list {
  overflow: auto;
}

div.block-list {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.block-list div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

div.list div {
  white-space: normal;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid white;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list block-list">
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum es el texto que se usa habitualmente en diseño gráfico en demostraciones de tipografías o de borradores de diseño para probar el diseño visual antes de insertar el texto final.
    </div>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum es el texto que se usa habitualmente en diseño gráfico en demostraciones de tipografías.
    </div>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum es el texto que se usa habitualmente en diseño gráfico en demostraciones de tipografías o de borradores de diseño para probar el diseño visual antes de insertar el texto final.
    </div>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum es el texto que se usa habitualmente en diseño gráfico en demostraciones de tipografías.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue with this implementation is that childs don't have same height. That's why I thought using flex:

```css
div.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 480px;
  margin: 24px 0;
}

div.list {
  overflow: auto;
}

div.flex-list {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.list div {
  white-space: normal;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid white;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list flex-list">
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum es el texto que se usa habitualmente en diseño gráfico en demostraciones de tipografías o de borradores de diseño para probar el diseño visual antes de insertar el texto final.
    </div>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum es el texto que se usa habitualmente en diseño gráfico en demostraciones de tipografías.
    </div>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum es el texto que se usa habitualmente en diseño gráfico en demostraciones de tipografías o de borradores de diseño para probar el diseño visual antes de insertar el texto final.
    </div>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum es el texto que se usa habitualmente en diseño gráfico en demostraciones de tipografías.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here they all do have same height. But the width is not respected and the problem is that content won't overflow..

Any idea how to achieve it using `flex`? (or the `inline-block` solution to have same height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable `flex-shrink`.

Add this to your code:

```
div.list div {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* new */
  white-space: normal;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid white;
  background: #eee;
}
```

A flex default setting is `flex-shrink: 1`, which causes items to shrink so that they don't overflow the container. If you want items to keep their defined width / height, then disable that setting.

```css
div.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 480px;
  margin: 24px 0;
}

div.list {
  overflow: auto;
}

div.flex-list {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.list div {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* new */
  white-space: normal;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid white;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list flex-list">
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum es el texto que se usa habitualmente en diseño gráfico en demostraciones de tipografías o de borradores de diseño para probar el diseño visual antes de insertar el texto final.
    </div>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum es el texto que se usa habitualmente en diseño gráfico en demostraciones de tipografías.
    </div>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum es el texto que se usa habitualmente en diseño gráfico en demostraciones de tipografías o de borradores de diseño para probar el diseño visual antes de insertar el texto final.
    </div>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum es el texto que se usa habitualmente en diseño gráfico en demostraciones de tipografías.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For a more detailed explanation see *"The `flex-shrink` Factor"* section in my answer here:

- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)

Comment: just noticed that with `min-width` works but thank you very mucho for pointing the `flex-shrink` ^^