# Why "flex: 0 0 50%" expands the parent container?

Tags: html, css

In [this](https://codepen.io/john-huang/pen/WNXrBQp?editors=1100) example, I want the **label** and **input** each to take up 50% of the parent **div** container. This should be able to achieve via either **width** or **flex** property. However, when I was doing the experiment to switch from "width" to "**flex: 0 0 50%**" the size of the parent container expands. Right now the sidebar size grows bigger than before. It got me wondering what leads to this **size expansion** even though the result still meets my need(label and input field each occupies 50% of the width of its container). Please take a look at the following CSS snippet:

```css
.form__label {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.form__input {
  width: 50%;
  /*   flex: 0 0 50%;
  min-width: 0; */
  padding: 0.3rem 1.1rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: var(--color-light--3);
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: It's definitely related to the flex-basis: 50rem you have set on the .sidebar container (you never set a specific width). It's a little hard to workout where the width is changing with all of the nested flex and grid - but this might help explain the flex behaviour in general: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352140/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-basis-and-width

Comment: Indeed, I've never specifically specified the width anywhere in the CSS. The flex-direction for .sidebar is column so the flex-basis corresponds to its height rather than width. Should I "always" specify the "width" in the outermost container just in case something weird like this happens again?

Comment: Yeah I'm especially for sidepanels I've found that having specific widths helps with lots of overflow/sizing issues! Also think that flax basis on .sidebar is effecting the width - try changing it to 100rem

Comment: @daggett
Gottcha thanks for your advice.