# Flex basis shrinks element but not parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am dealing with a flex-box issue. It seems that a flex item with flex basis is shrunk accordingly but the parent maintains its size as if the child still occupied its full size.

These two images are the exact same code except the `.earnings-claim-wrapper` in the second one does not have the flex property. The last image shows how chrome "represents" that empty space.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Expected behaviour:

[image]

I've reduced the code to this:

```css
div{
  padding:10px;
}
.earnings-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}

.earnings-info-container {
  background-color: orange;
}

.earnings-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: green;
}

.earnings-info .earnings-claim {
  align-self: flex-start;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.earnings-claim-wrapper {
  flex: 0 1 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="earnings-container">
    <div class="earnings-info-container">
        <div class="earnings-info">
            <div class="earnings-icon student-points"></div>
            <div class="earnings-title">earnings-title</div>
            <div class="earnings-claim-wrapper">
                <div class="earnings-claim not-enough-effort">earnings-claim</div>
                <span class="effort-message">Some long text text text text text text long text</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="earnings-info-container">
        <div class="earnings-info">
            <div class="earnings-icon diamonds"></div>
            <div class="earnings-title">earnings-title</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The second image is the desired result?

Comment: none of them, the desired result would be the first one but the parent shrinking to fit the content. Instead, the parent keeps the same size as if the child did not have the flex property, with a big empty space (with dotted lines in the last image). Is this clearer?

Comment: Nope, not for me at least... can you add an image of the desired result?

Comment: yes sure... done

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `flex: 0 1 100px;` on `earnings-claim-wrapper` class, use `width:100px;`

```css
div{
  padding:10px;
}
.earnings-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}

.earnings-info-container {
  background-color: orange;
}

.earnings-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: green;
}

.earnings-info .earnings-claim {
  align-self: flex-start;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.earnings-claim-wrapper {
  width:100px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="earnings-container">
    <div class="earnings-info-container">
        <div class="earnings-info">
            <div class="earnings-icon student-points"></div>
            <div class="earnings-title">earnings-title</div>
            <div class="earnings-claim-wrapper">
                <div class="earnings-claim not-enough-effort">earnings-claim</div>
                <span class="effort-message">Some long text text text text text text long text</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="earnings-info-container">
        <div class="earnings-info">
            <div class="earnings-icon diamonds"></div>
            <div class="earnings-title">earnings-title</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well I guess that would have been a quick solution yes! Maybe I did not try, not sure. Still wonder the logic behind my code not working, thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I've got to be honest that I can't fully reproduce what happens in your code that makes `.earning-info` expand. But I did find out it has to do with setting a `flex-basis` on the `.earnings-claim-wrapper` elements.

Giving all it's parents a `flex-basis` as well did the trick here.

Also, I think you can remove some properties, I've commented them out in the snippet.

```css
div{
  padding:10px;
}
.earnings-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}

.earnings-info-container {
  flex: 0 1 1%;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.earnings-info {
  flex: 0 1 1%;
  display: flex;
  /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
  /*justify-content: left;*/
  /*align-items: flex-start;*/
  background-color: green;
}

.earnings-info .earnings-claim {
  /*align-self: flex-start;*/
  background-color: yellow;
}

.earnings-claim-wrapper {
  flex: 0 1 100px;
  /*position: relative;
  display: flex;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="earnings-container">
    <div class="earnings-info-container">
        <div class="earnings-info">
            <div class="earnings-icon student-points">x</div>
            <div class="earnings-title">earnings-title</div>
            <div class="earnings-claim-wrapper">
                <div class="earnings-claim not-enough-effort">earnings-claim</div>
                <span class="effort-message">Some long text text text text text text long text</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="earnings-info-container">
        <div class="earnings-info">
            <div class="earnings-icon diamonds">x</div>
            <div class="earnings-title">earnings-title</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Weird right? What if I don't want the earnings-title to wrap? In my real code I had a table inside and some other things. Adding flex-basis to the other components makes it shrink. (I see now in my last image it was unintentionally wrapped) To be honest I ended up changing my approach to something that worked so I'm good now, but it really bugged me no understanding the logic of it

Comment: Maybe I am missing something there but it seems Scario Eva solution is quite simple and works

Comment: You might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34355447/1930721 . Quote "flex-basis applies only to flex items. Flex containers (that aren't also flex items) will ignore flex-basis but can use width and height."

Comment: According to this though, `flex-basis:100px` and  `width:100px` should render equally (given that flex direction is row) right? but they don't