# CSS managing overflow inside a flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

I am trying to build a "carousel" into my webpage, a little bit like netflix's homepage. So there should be multiple elements where the user can click to scroll to the next one. I have all the elements lined up and an idea of how to make the clicking functionality work, but the boxes I have make the container extend beyond the page even though I have set overflow-x to hidden. Here's a stripped down version of my code

```css
body, html{
  margin:0;
}
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
}
.navigation{
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}
.contents{
  flex-grow:1;
  background-color:red;
}
.wrapper{
  background-color:green;
  width:90%;
  height:90%;
  margin:auto;
}
.carousel{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
.box{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:yellow;
  margin:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navigation"></div>
  <div class="contents">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="carousel">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The idea is that *container* is 100% of the width, *navigation* is 200px, and *wrapper* takes up the remaining width. *Wrapper*'s only child is *carousel* whose width is 100%, and whose overflow is hidden. Why is container trying to extend beyond the page? And how can I fix this?
Here's a screenshot I got of the results: The ideal situation is no scrollbar on the bottom.
[Page with scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR8mt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Few issues you have to address. Here's the list and working code below:

- [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)
- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276) (see "The `flex-shrink` factor" in main answer)
- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

```css
.container{
  /* width: 100%; */ /* not necessary; block elements full width by default */
  height:100vh;      /* changed from %; no reliance on parent element */
  display:flex;
}
.navigation{
  width:200px;       /* can shrink in a flex container (default setting) */
  /* height:100%; */ /* not necessary; align-items:stretch default */
  background-color:blue;
  flex-shrink: 0;    /* disable flex-shrink:1 default */
}
.contents{
  flex-grow:1;
  background-color:red;
  min-width: 0;     /* override min-width:auto default */
}
.wrapper{
  background-color:green;
  width:90%;
  height:90vh;      /* modified; see second note above */
  margin:auto;
}
.carousel{
  /* width:100%; */ /* not necessary */
  display:flex;
  overflow-x: auto; /* auto for demo; switch to hidden */
}
.box{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:yellow;
  margin:15px;
  flex-shrink: 0;    /* disable flex shrink (see comments above) */
}
body, html{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navigation"></div>
  <div class="contents">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="carousel">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```