# flex-basis property is not working when display: inline-flex and felx-direction: row, but it is working when flex-direction:column

Tags: flexbox

my question is why flex-basis is not working when display: inline-flex and felx-direction: row but its working when display: inline-flex and felx-direction: column ? I am kind of new to coding please try to explain with simple words as possible.

```
<style>
    .container {
      color: white;
      border: 5px solid gold;
      display: inline-flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .container > div {
      flex-basis: 250px;
    }
   
    /*
Select all the elements that are the direct
children of the .container class.
    */

    .red {background-color: #eb4d4b;}
    .orange {background-color: #f0932b;}
    .yellow {background-color: #f6e58d;}
    .green {background-color: #6ab04c;}
    .blue {background-color: #4834d4;}
    .indigo {background-color: #30336b;}
    .purple {background-color: #be2edd;}
  </style>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="red">Red</div>
    <div class="orange">Orange</div>
    <div class="yellow">Yellow</div>
    <div class="green">Green</div>
    <div class="blue">Blue</div>
    <div class="indigo">Indigo</div>
    <div class="purple">Purple</div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

tried to change flex-direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Understanding `flex-basis`:**

- `flex-basis` sets the initial size of a flex item **before** any available space is distributed.
- It affects the **main dimension** of the flex container **(width for rows, height for columns)**.

**The Key Difference:**

- **Inline-flex containers behave like text elements.** They shrink-wrap their contents to fit the smallest possible width.
- This shrinking behavior can override `flex-basis` in a row-based layout because **width is the main dimension for rows**.

**How to Make It Work:**

If your trying to use flex-basis to set the width of your elements;

1. **Set an explicit width on the element:**

```css
.container {
      color: white;
      border: 5px solid gold;
      display: inline-flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

.container > div {
  width: 250px;
}
```

2. **Use block-level flexbox**

```css
.container {
  display: flex; /* Use regular flexbox for better control over width */
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container > div {
  flex-basis: 250px; /* Now flex-basis will work as expected */
}
```

Also check out this great answers for a better understanding of `flex-basis`

[What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352140/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-basis-and-width?rq=2)

Comment: Also check out this article from freeCodeCamp [Even more about how Flexbox works —explained in big, colorful, animated gifs](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/even-more-about-how-flexbox-works-explained-in-big-colorful-animated-gifs-a5a74812b053/)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, now i understand what you mean i deleted my previous comment :)